# Two dimensional bicubic interpolation implementation in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, image, numerical-methods, matlab

I am attempting to implement two dimensional [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) algorithm in Matlab. The input is a two dimensional array and the output is the interpolated result.

The test input matrix:

```
input = [1 1 50 50
         1 1 50 50
         10 5 40 40
         30 30 40 50];
```

The output result:

[image: TwoDimensionalBicubicInterpolation]

**The experimental implementation**

- `BicubicInterpolation` function implementation:

  ```
  function [output] = BicubicInterpolation(input, newSize)
      originSize = size(input);
      newSizeX = newSize(1);
      newSizeY = newSize(2);
      output = zeros(newSize(1), newSize(2));
      ratiox = originSize(1) / newSizeX;
      ratioy = originSize(2) / newSizeY;

      for y = 0:newSizeY - 1
          for x = 0:newSizeX - 1
              xMappingToOrigin = x * ratiox;
              yMappingToOrigin = y * ratioy;
              xMappingToOriginFloor = floor(xMappingToOrigin);
              yMappingToOriginFloor = floor(yMappingToOrigin);
              xMappingToOriginFrac = xMappingToOrigin - xMappingToOriginFloor;
              yMappingToOriginFrac = yMappingToOrigin - yMappingToOriginFloor;

              ndata = zeros(4, 4);
              for ndatay = -1:2
                  for ndatax = -1:2
                      ndata(ndatax + 2, ndatay + 2) = input( ...
                          clip(xMappingToOriginFloor + ndatax, 0, originSize(1) - 1) + 1, ...
                          clip(yMappingToOriginFloor + ndatay, 0, originSize(2) - 1) + 1);
                  end
              end
              output(x + 1, y + 1) = BicubicPolate(ndata, xMappingToOriginFrac, yMappingToOriginFrac);
          end
      end
  end
  ```
- The other used functions:

  ```
  function [output] = clip(input, lowerbound, upperbound)
      if (input > upperbound)
          output = upperbound;
          return;
      end
      if (input < lowerbound)
          output = lowerbound;
          return;
      end
      output = input;
  end

  function [output] = BicubicPolate(ndata, fracx, fracy)
      x1 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,1), ndata(2,1), ndata(3,1), ndata(4,1), fracx );
      x2 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,2), ndata(2,2), ndata(3,2), ndata(4,2), fracx );
      x3 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,3), ndata(2,3), ndata(3,3), ndata(4,3), fracx );
      x4 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,4), ndata(2,4), ndata(3,4), ndata(4,4), fracx );

      output = CubicPolate( x1, x2, x3, x4, fracy );
  end

  function [output] = CubicPolate(v0, v1, v2, v3, fracy )
      A = (v3-v2)-(v0-v1);
      B = (v0-v1)-A;
      C = v2-v0;
      D = v1;
      output =  D + fracy * (C + fracy * (B + fracy * A));
  end
  ```
- The testing code for generating the result above:

  ```
  input = [1 1 50 50
           1 1 50 50
           10 5 40 40
           30 30 40 50];
  outputSize = [100, 100];

  output = BicubicInterpolation(input, outputSize);

  figure;
  subplot(1, 4, 1);
  surf(input);
  title("input");
  colorbar;

  subplot(1, 4, 2);
  surf(output);
  title("output");
  colorbar;

  subplot(1, 4, 3);
  surf(imresize(input, outputSize, 'bicubic'));
  title("built-in bicubic");
  colorbar;

  subplot(1, 4, 4);
  surf(imresize(input, outputSize, 'bilinear'));
  title("built-in bilinear");
  colorbar;
  ```

**The full testing code**

The full testing code for performing bicubic interpolation with lena image.

```
% Develop by Jimmy Hu
input = imread('lena2.bmp');
input = rgb2gray(input);
input = imresize(input, [200 200], 'nearest');

outputSize = [1000, 1000];

output = BicubicInterpolation(input, outputSize);

figure;
subplot(1, 4, 1);
imshow(input);
title("input");
colorbar;

subplot(1, 4, 2);
imshow(output./255);
title("output");
colorbar;

subplot(1, 4, 3);
imshow(imresize(input, outputSize, 'bicubic'));
title("built-in bicubic");
colorbar;

subplot(1, 4, 4);
imshow(imresize(input, outputSize, 'bilinear'));
title("built-in bilinear");
colorbar;

function [output] = BicubicInterpolation(input, newSize)
    originSize = size(input);
    newSizeX = newSize(1);
    newSizeY = newSize(2);
    output = zeros(newSize(1), newSize(2));
    ratiox = originSize(1) / newSizeX;
    ratioy = originSize(2) / newSizeY;

    for y = 0:newSizeY - 1
        for x = 0:newSizeX - 1
            xMappingToOrigin = x * ratiox;
            yMappingToOrigin = y * ratioy;
            xMappingToOriginFloor = floor(xMappingToOrigin);
            yMappingToOriginFloor = floor(yMappingToOrigin);
            xMappingToOriginFrac = xMappingToOrigin - xMappingToOriginFloor;
            yMappingToOriginFrac = yMappingToOrigin - yMappingToOriginFloor;

            ndata = zeros(4, 4);
            for ndatay = -1:2
                for ndatax = -1:2
                    ndata(ndatax + 2, ndatay + 2) = input( ...
                        clip(xMappingToOriginFloor + ndatax, 0, originSize(1) - 1) + 1, ...
                        clip(yMappingToOriginFloor + ndatay, 0, originSize(2) - 1) + 1);
                end
            end
            output(x + 1, y + 1) = BicubicPolate(ndata, xMappingToOriginFrac, yMappingToOriginFrac);
        end
    end
end

function [output] = clip(input, lowerbound, upperbound)
    if (input > upperbound)
        output = upperbound;
        return;
    end
    if (input < lowerbound)
        output = lowerbound;
        return;
    end
    output = input;
end

function [output] = BicubicPolate(ndata, fracx, fracy)
    x1 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,1), ndata(2,1), ndata(3,1), ndata(4,1), fracx );
    x2 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,2), ndata(2,2), ndata(3,2), ndata(4,2), fracx );
    x3 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,3), ndata(2,3), ndata(3,3), ndata(4,3), fracx );
    x4 = CubicPolate( ndata(1,4), ndata(2,4), ndata(3,4), ndata(4,4), fracx );

    output = CubicPolate( x1, x2, x3, x4, fracy );
end

function [output] = CubicPolate(v0, v1, v2, v3, fracy )
    A = (v3-v2)-(v0-v1);
    B = (v0-v1)-A;
    C = v2-v0;
    D = v1;
    output =  D + fracy * (C + fracy * (B + fracy * A));
end
```

[image: LenaBicubicInterpolation]

Notes: The `lena2.bmp` here is a 512 * 512 size color image.

All suggestions are welcome.

#### Reference

- [Bicubic Interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20924576/6667035)
- [The Lenna Story](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Echuck/lennapg/)