# Two dimensional gaussian image generator in C++

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, image, template, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [Two dimensional bicubic interpolation implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263289/231235) and [Two dimensional gaussian image generator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263024/231235). Based on [user673679's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263320/231235), another file `image_operations.h` is created for those non-member helper functions for image operations implementation. Moreover, the two dimensional gaussian image generator `gaussianFigure2D` and `gaussianFigure2D2` is implemented as below.

- `Image` template class implementation (`image.h`):

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #ifndef Image_H
  #define Image_H

  #include <algorithm>
  #include <array>
  #include <chrono>
  #include <complex>
  #include <concepts>
  #include <functional>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iterator>
  #include <list>
  #include <numeric>
  #include <string>
  #include <type_traits>
  #include <variant>
  #include <vector>
  #include "basic_functions.h"
  #include "image_operations.h"

  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      template <typename ElementT>
      class Image
      {
      public:
          Image()
          {
          }

          Image(const size_t width, const size_t height):
              width(width),
              height(height),
              image_data(width * height) { }

          Image(const int width, const int height, const ElementT initVal):
              width(width),
              height(height),
              image_data(width * height)
          {
              this->image_data = recursive_transform<1>(this->image_data, [initVal](ElementT element) { return initVal; });
              return;
          }

          Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, size_t newWidth, size_t newHeight)
          {
              this->width = newWidth;
              this->height = newHeight;
              this->image_data = recursive_transform<1>(input, [](ElementT element) { return element; });   //  Deep copy
          }

          Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
          {
              this->height = input.size();
              this->width = input[0].size();

              for (auto& rows : input)
              {
                  this->image_data.insert(this->image_data.end(), std::begin(input), std::end(input));
              }
              return;
          }

          constexpr ElementT& at(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y) { return this->image_data[y * width + x]; }

          constexpr ElementT const& at(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y) const { return this->image_data[y * width + x]; }

          constexpr size_t getWidth()
          {
              return this->width;
          }

          constexpr size_t getHeight()
          {
              return this->height;
          }

          std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const { return this->image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

          void print()
          {
              for (size_t y = 0; y < this->height; y++)
              {
                  for (size_t x = 0; x < this->width; x++)
                  {
                      //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                      std::cout << +this->at(x, y) << "\t";
                  }
                  std::cout << "\n";
              }
              std::cout << "\n";
              return;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              for (size_t y = 0; y < this->height; y++)
              {
                  for (size_t x = 0; x < this->width; x++)
                  {
                      this->at(x, y) += rhs.at(x, y);
                  }
              }
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator=(Image<ElementT> const& input) = default;  //  Copy Assign

          Image<ElementT>& operator=(Image<ElementT>&& other) = default;       //  Move Assign

          Image(const Image<ElementT> &input) = default;                       //  Copy Constructor

          Image(Image<ElementT> &&input) = default;                            //  Move Constructor

      private:
          size_t width;
          size_t height;
          std::vector<ElementT> image_data;
      };
  }
  #endif
  ```
- `image_operations.h`: non-member helper functions for image operations.

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #ifndef ImageOperations_H
  #define ImageOperations_H

  #include "base_types.h"
  #include "image.h"

  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      // Forward Declaration class Image
      template <typename ElementT>
      class Image;

      template<class ElementT>
      Image<ElementT> copyResizeBicubic(Image<ElementT> const& image, size_t width, size_t height)
      {
          auto output = Image<ElementT>(width, height);
          auto ratiox = (float)image.getWidth() / (float)width;
          auto ratioy = (float)image.getHeight() / (float)height;

          for (size_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
          {
              for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
              {
                  float xMappingToOrigin = (float)x * ratiox;
                  float yMappingToOrigin = (float)y * ratioy;
                  float xMappingToOriginFloor = floor(xMappingToOrigin);
                  float yMappingToOriginFloor = floor(yMappingToOrigin);
                  float xMappingToOriginFrac = xMappingToOrigin - xMappingToOriginFloor;
                  float yMappingToOriginFrac = yMappingToOrigin - yMappingToOriginFloor;

                  ElementT ndata[4 * 4];
                  for (int ndatay = -1; ndatay <= 2; ndatay++)
                  {
                      for (int ndatax = -1; ndatax <= 2; ndatax++)
                      {
                          ndata[(ndatay + 1) * 4 + (ndatax + 1)] = image.at(
                              std::clamp(xMappingToOriginFloor + ndatax, 0.0f, image.getWidth() - 1.0f), 
                              std::clamp(yMappingToOriginFloor + ndatay, 0.0f, image.getHeight() - 1.0f));
                      }

                  }
                  output.at(x, y) = bicubicPolate(ndata, xMappingToOriginFrac, yMappingToOriginFrac);
              }
          }
          return output;
      }

      template<class ElementT, class InputT>
      constexpr static auto bicubicPolate(const ElementT* const ndata, const InputT fracx, const InputT fracy)
      {
          auto x1 = cubicPolate( ndata[0], ndata[1], ndata[2], ndata[3], fracx );
          auto x2 = cubicPolate( ndata[4], ndata[5], ndata[6], ndata[7], fracx );
          auto x3 = cubicPolate( ndata[8], ndata[9], ndata[10], ndata[11], fracx );
          auto x4 = cubicPolate( ndata[12], ndata[13], ndata[14], ndata[15], fracx );

          return std::clamp(cubicPolate( x1, x2, x3, x4, fracy ), 0.0f, 255.0f);
      }

      template<class InputT1, class InputT2>
      constexpr static auto cubicPolate(const InputT1 v0, const InputT1 v1, const InputT1 v2, const InputT1 v3, const InputT2 frac)
      {
          auto A = (v3-v2)-(v0-v1);
          auto B = (v0-v1)-A;
          auto C = v2-v0;
          auto D = v1;
          return D + frac * (C + frac * (B + frac * A));
      }

      //  single standard deviation
      template<class InputT>
      constexpr static Image<InputT> gaussianFigure2D(
          const size_t xsize, const size_t ysize,
          const size_t centerx, const size_t centery,
          const InputT standard_deviation)
      {
          return gaussianFigure2D2(xsize, ysize, centerx, centery, standard_deviation, standard_deviation);
      }

      //  multiple standard deviations
      template<class InputT>
      constexpr static Image<InputT> gaussianFigure2D2(
          const size_t xsize, const size_t ysize, 
          const size_t centerx, const size_t centery,
          const InputT standard_deviation_x, const InputT standard_deviation_y)
      {
          auto output = TinyDIP::Image<InputT>(xsize, ysize);
          auto row_vector_x = TinyDIP::Image<InputT>(xsize, 1);
          for (size_t x = 0; x < xsize; x++)
          {
              row_vector_x.at(x, 0) = normalDistribution1D(static_cast<InputT>(x) - static_cast<InputT>(centerx), standard_deviation_x);
          }

          auto row_vector_y = TinyDIP::Image<InputT>(ysize, 1);
          for (size_t y = 0; y < ysize; y++)
          {
              row_vector_y.at(y, 0) = normalDistribution1D(static_cast<InputT>(y) - static_cast<InputT>(centery), standard_deviation_y);
          }

          for (size_t y = 0; y < ysize; y++)
          {
              for (size_t x = 0; x < xsize; x++)
              {
                  output.at(x, y) = row_vector_x.at(x, 0) * row_vector_y.at(y, 0);
              }
          }
          return output;
      }

      float normalDistribution1D(const float x, const float standard_deviation)
      {
          return expf(-x * x / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation));
      }

      double normalDistribution1D(const double x, const double standard_deviation)
      {
          return exp(-x * x / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation));
      }

      long double normalDistribution1D(const long double x, const long double standard_deviation)
      {
          return expl(-x * x / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation));
      }

      float normalDistribution2D(const float xlocation, const float ylocation, const float standard_deviation)
      {
          return expf(-(xlocation * xlocation + ylocation * ylocation) / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation)) / (2 * M_PI * standard_deviation * standard_deviation);
      }

      double normalDistribution2D(const double xlocation, const double ylocation, const double standard_deviation)
      {
          return exp(-(xlocation * xlocation + ylocation * ylocation) / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation)) / (2 * M_PI * standard_deviation * standard_deviation);
      }
  }

  #endif
  ```
- `basic_functions.h`: The basic functions

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #ifndef BasicFunctions_H
  #define BasicFunctions_H

  #include <algorithm>
  #include <array>
  #include <cassert>
  #include <chrono>
  #include <complex>
  #include <concepts>
  #include <deque>
  #include <execution>
  #include <exception>
  #include <functional>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iterator>
  #include <list>
  #include <map>
  #include <mutex>
  #include <numeric>
  #include <optional>
  #include <ranges>
  #include <stdexcept>
  #include <string>
  #include <tuple>
  #include <type_traits>
  #include <utility>
  #include <variant>
  #include <vector>

  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      template<typename T>
      concept is_back_inserterable = requires(T x)
      {
          std::back_inserter(x);
      };

      template<typename T>
      concept is_inserterable = requires(T x)
      {
          std::inserter(x, std::ranges::end(x));
      };

      //  recursive_invoke_result_t implementation
      template<typename, typename>
      struct recursive_invoke_result { };

      template<typename T, std::invocable<T> F>
      struct recursive_invoke_result<F, T> { using type = std::invoke_result_t<F, T>; };

      template<typename F, template<typename...> typename Container, typename... Ts>
      requires (
          !std::invocable<F, Container<Ts...>>&&
          std::ranges::input_range<Container<Ts...>>&&
          requires { typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type; })
          struct recursive_invoke_result<F, Container<Ts...>>
      {
          using type = Container<typename recursive_invoke_result<F, std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<Ts...>>>::type>;
      };

      template<typename F, typename T>
      using recursive_invoke_result_t = typename recursive_invoke_result<F, T>::type;

      //  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level)
      template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class T, class F>
      constexpr auto recursive_transform(const T& input, const F& f)
      {
          if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
          {
              recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
              std::ranges::transform(
                  std::ranges::cbegin(input),
                  std::ranges::cend(input),
                  std::inserter(output, std::ranges::end(output)),
                  [&f](auto&& element) { return recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(element, f); }
              );
              return output;
          }
          else
          {
              return f(input);
          }
      }

      //  recursive_transform implementation (the version with unwrap_level, with execution policy)
      template<std::size_t unwrap_level = 1, class ExPo, class T, class F>
      requires (std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
      constexpr auto recursive_transform(ExPo execution_policy, const T& input, const F& f)
      {
          if constexpr (unwrap_level > 0)
          {
              recursive_invoke_result_t<F, T> output{};
              std::mutex mutex;

              //  Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each
              std::for_each(execution_policy, input.cbegin(), input.cend(),
                  [&](auto&& element)
                  {
                      auto result = recursive_transform<unwrap_level - 1>(execution_policy, element, f);
                      std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
                      output.emplace_back(std::move(result));
                  }
              );

              return output;
          }
          else
          {
              return f(input);
          }
      }

      template<std::size_t dim, class T>
      constexpr auto n_dim_vector_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
      {
          if constexpr (dim == 0)
          {
              return input;
          }
          else
          {
              auto element = n_dim_vector_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
              std::vector<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
              return output;
          }
      }

      template<std::size_t dim, std::size_t times, class T>
      constexpr auto n_dim_array_generator(T input)
      {
          if constexpr (dim == 0)
          {
              return input;
          }
          else
          {
              auto element = n_dim_array_generator<dim - 1, times>(input);
              std::array<decltype(element), times> output;
              std::fill(std::ranges::begin(output), std::ranges::end(output), element);
              return output;
          }
      }

      template<std::size_t dim, class T>
      constexpr auto n_dim_deque_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
      {
          if constexpr (dim == 0)
          {
              return input;
          }
          else
          {
              auto element = n_dim_deque_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
              std::deque<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
              return output;
          }
      }

      template<std::size_t dim, class T>
      constexpr auto n_dim_list_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
      {
          if constexpr (dim == 0)
          {
              return input;
          }
          else
          {
              auto element = n_dim_list_generator<dim - 1>(input, times);
              std::list<decltype(element)> output(times, element);
              return output;
          }
      }

      template<std::size_t dim, template<class...> class Container = std::vector, class T>
      constexpr auto n_dim_container_generator(T input, std::size_t times)
      {
          if constexpr (dim == 0)
          {
              return input;
          }
          else
          {
              return Container(times, n_dim_container_generator<dim - 1, Container, T>(input, times));
          }
      }
  }

  #endif
  ```
- `base_types.h`: The base types

  ```
  /* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

  #ifndef BASE_H
  #define BASE_H

  #include <cmath>
  #include <cstdbool>
  #include <cstdio>
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <string>

  #define MAX_PATH 256
  #define FILE_ROOT_PATH "./"

  typedef unsigned char BYTE;

  typedef struct RGB
  {
      unsigned char channels[3];
  } RGB;

  typedef BYTE GrayScale;

  typedef struct HSV
  {
      long double channels[3];    //  Range: 0 <= H < 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 255
  }HSV;

  #endif
  ```

**The full testing code**

```
/* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

#include "base_types.h"
#include "basic_functions.h"
#include "image.h"
#include "image_operations.h"

void gaussianFigure2DTest();

int main()
{
    gaussianFigure2DTest();
    return 0;
}

void gaussianFigure2DTest()
{
    auto image1 = TinyDIP::gaussianFigure2D2(10, 10, 5, 5, 3.0, 1.0);
    image1.print();

    auto image2 = TinyDIP::gaussianFigure2D(10, 10, 5, 5, 3.0);
    image2.print();
    return;
}
```

The output of the testing code above:

```
9.29249e-07     1.53207e-06     2.26033e-06     2.98407e-06     3.52526e-06     3.72665e-06     3.52526e-06     2.98407e-06     2.26033e-06     1.53207e-06
8.36483e-05     0.000137913     0.000203468     0.000268617     0.000317334     0.000335463     0.000317334     0.000268617     0.000203468     0.000137913
0.00277005      0.00456705      0.00673795      0.00889539      0.0105087       0.011109        0.0105087       0.00889539      0.00673795      0.00456705
0.0337462       0.055638        0.082085        0.108368        0.128022        0.135335        0.128022        0.108368        0.082085        0.055638
0.15124 0.249352        0.367879        0.485672        0.573753        0.606531        0.573753        0.485672        0.367879        0.249352
0.249352        0.411112        0.606531        0.800737        0.945959        1       0.945959        0.800737        0.606531        0.411112
0.15124 0.249352        0.367879        0.485672        0.573753        0.606531        0.573753        0.485672        0.367879        0.249352
0.0337462       0.055638        0.082085        0.108368        0.128022        0.135335        0.128022        0.108368        0.082085        0.055638
0.00277005      0.00456705      0.00673795      0.00889539      0.0105087       0.011109        0.0105087       0.00889539      0.00673795      0.00456705
8.36483e-05     0.000137913     0.000203468     0.000268617     0.000317334     0.000335463     0.000317334     0.000268617     0.000203468     0.000137913

0.0621765       0.102512        0.15124 0.199666        0.235877        0.249352        0.235877        0.199666        0.15124 0.102512
0.102512        0.169013        0.249352        0.329193        0.388896        0.411112        0.388896        0.329193        0.249352        0.169013
0.15124 0.249352        0.367879        0.485672        0.573753        0.606531        0.573753        0.485672        0.367879        0.249352
0.199666        0.329193        0.485672        0.64118 0.757465        0.800737        0.757465        0.64118 0.485672        0.329193
0.235877        0.388896        0.573753        0.757465        0.894839        0.945959        0.894839        0.757465        0.573753        0.388896
0.249352        0.411112        0.606531        0.800737        0.945959        1       0.945959        0.800737        0.606531        0.411112
0.235877        0.388896        0.573753        0.757465        0.894839        0.945959        0.894839        0.757465        0.573753        0.388896
0.199666        0.329193        0.485672        0.64118 0.757465        0.800737        0.757465        0.64118 0.485672        0.329193
0.15124 0.249352        0.367879        0.485672        0.573753        0.606531        0.573753        0.485672        0.367879        0.249352
0.102512        0.169013        0.249352        0.329193        0.388896        0.411112        0.388896        0.329193        0.249352        0.169013
```

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Two dimensional bicubic interpolation implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263289/231235) and

  [Two dimensional gaussian image generator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263024/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  Based on [user673679's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263320/231235), another file `image_operations.h` is created for those non-member helper functions for image operations implementation. Moreover, I am attempting to build the two dimensional gaussian image generator functions in C++.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

#### Reference

- Multivariate normal distribution

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Comment: You mean "developed by Jimmy Hu".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are obviously on a fantastic quest to understand how to implement image processing operations in all sorts of languages. The tag [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) tells me that you know that you should use an established image processing library as the basis of any serious work.

Here are some comments on your C++ implementation.

## image.h

Proper English spelling would be "Develop**ed** by Jimmy Hu".

This file includes headers that you don't use. You should only include headers that you actually need.

```cpp
        Image()
        {
        }
```

This should be

```cpp
        Image() = default;
```

This constructor initializes the array with a constant value:

```cpp
        Image(const int width, const int height, const ElementT initVal):
            width(width),
            height(height),
            image_data(width * height)
        {
            this->image_data = recursive_transform<1>(this->image_data, [initVal](ElementT element) { return initVal; });
            return;
        }
```

Use the `std::vector` constructor for this:

```cpp
        Image(const int width, const int height, const ElementT initVal):
            width(width),
            height(height),
            image_data(width * height, initVal) {}
```

If you further add a default value to the last parameter (`const ElementT initVal = {}`) then you don't need the previous constructor (`Image(const size_t width, const size_t height)`).

```cpp
        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, size_t newWidth, size_t newHeight)
        {
            this->width = newWidth;
            this->height = newHeight;
            this->image_data = recursive_transform<1>(input, [](ElementT element) { return element; });   //  Deep copy
        }
```

This constructor can be easily implemented in terms of `std::copy`. You do need to add a test here to verify that the input array has the right number of elements considering `newWidth` and `newHeight`.

The implementation of `at` doesn't check bounds. I would suggest adding `assert` statements for bounds, to catch bugs in debug mode. A release build would then not test bounds.

`operator+=` should really test that the sizes of the second image match those of the first. You can then simply iterate over the two arrays without worrying about `x` and `y` coordinates. If sizes don't match, the operation should fail.

It is not necessary to use `this->` to access members. Some people like it, but I think it is superfluous.

The standard way to increment in C++ is `++x`, not `x++`. For an `int` it doesn't make any difference, but for more complex objects it could be very wasteful. `++x` increments the variable, then returns its value. `x++` makes a copy of the value of the variable, increments the variable, then returns the copy. If you are not using the value of the expression, use the pre-increment to avoid the unnecessary copy.

## image_operations.h

You don't need to forward declare `class Image`. You include its header file, so the class is already declared.

```cpp
auto ratiox = (float)image.getWidth() / (float)width;
```

Please get used to the C++ way of casting:

```cpp
auto ratiox = static_cast<float>(image.getWidth()) / static_cast<float>(width);
```

It is a more obvious cast and makes your code more readable.

Your functions `gaussianFigure2D` and `gaussianFigure2D2` don't need different names. I would argue the library would be easier to use if they had the same name. The compiler will pick the one or the other function depending on the arguments passed.

`std::exp` is implemented for all three floating-point types. Consequently, `normalDistribution1D` can be implemented as a template:

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    T normalDistribution1D(const T x, const T standard_deviation)
    {
        return std::exp(-x * x / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation));
    }
```

The same is true for `normalDistribution2D`.

Functions here are declared out of order: functions use other functions that are declared later in the file. Somehow this works for you, I think, because templates are instantiated when used. It would be better practice to declare `normalDistribution1D` before `gaussianFigure2D`, and `gaussianFigure2D2` before `gaussianFigure2D`. Note that class methods can be declared in any order -- the compiler will first collect all member names (collect the full definition of the class) before attempting to compile each of the function bodies. The same is not true for free functions such as the ones we're talking about here.

## basic_functions.h

Again you have way too many headers included here.

This is very complex code, which seems out of place with the relatively straight-forward C++ code elsewhere. With the changes suggested above, you don't need this file at all.

## base_types.h

You should not be using `<cstdbool>`. [It is deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdbool) The other `<c...>` headers should not be needed either. Use the C++ library, not the C library.

Instead of `#define MAX_PATH 256`, use `constexpr int MAX_PATH = 256`. Preprocessor macros are nice to generate code, but they should not be used for things that you can do with native C++ constructs.

Likewise, instead of the C construct `typedef unsigned char BYTE`, use `using BYTE = unsigned char`, which is, to me, much more readable.

This is also a C thing:

```cpp
typedef struct RGB
{
    unsigned char channels[3];
} RGB;
```

In C++ it is just

```cpp
struct RGB
{
    unsigned char channels[3];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answering. _Your functions `gaussianFigure2D` and `gaussianFigure2D2` don't need different names. I would argue the library would be easier to use if they had the same name. The compiler will pick the one or the other function depending on the arguments passed._ I found a thing is that the compiler (`g++-11 11.1.0`) says "error: no matching function for call to 'gaussianFigure2D(const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&, const double&, const double&)'" if those functions with same name.

Comment: However, if the single standard deviation version definition is put _after_ the multiple standard deviations version definition, there is no error occurred.

Comment: @JimmyHu: Wow, that’s weird. What compiler do you use? I would logically place the function that contains the actual code first, and the “aliases” with different inputs after, but the order shouldn’t matter for the compiler.

Comment: g++ under MacOS:

g++-11 (Homebrew GCC 11.1.0_1) 11.1.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: @JimmyHu: Thanks, I have the same compiler on macOS, I want to play with this to see if I can figure out the reason.

Comment: Thank you for trying. If you figure out the reason, please let me know.

Comment: @JimmyHu When you first mentioned the issue with the order, I had forgotten that we're not talking about class member functions, but free functions. Things are different there. I have added some text to this respect in the answer, I hope that clarifies things. If you make sure to compile with `-Wall`, the compiler will warn you about lots of things that are not really OK, but it can work around. You get best code when you fix all warnings generated by this flag.

Comment: I don't find C++ casts particularly readable.  But I'd argue that's a good thing - it encourages us to really question which casts really are necessary, and eliminate the rest.  It may even make me write that one as `1.0f * image.getWidth() / width` to use standard conversions instead.  C++ casts are _safer_ than C casts, because it's clearer which aspects you intend to change (e.g. you can't accidentally cast away `const`).

Answer (score 4):

`"error: no matching function for call to 'gaussianFigure2D(const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&, const size_t&, const double&, const double&)'"`

Here is how your code defines it:

```
template<class InputT>
    constexpr static Image<InputT> gaussianFigure2D(
        const size_t xsize, const size_t ysize,
        const size_t centerx, const size_t centery,
        const InputT standard_deviation)
```

and the other form just has one more parameter.

Here's where it is called:
`auto image1 = TinyDIP::gaussianFigure2D2(10, 10, 5, 5, 3.0, 1.0);`

That looks like it should work just fine.  Since there are a different number of parameters, it will pick the one with 6 parameters and not get confused as to which you meant.  The template argument deduction and conversions would not be any different when this is overloaded.

Having the second form simply supply the 6th argument automatically duplicating the 5th is a perfect use case for overloading!

I think your problem is that you defined them in the wrong order.  The 6-argument form goes *first*, so the 5-argument form can call it.  It worked as-written, even though `gaussianFigure2D2` is not declared yet, because this is a template body and the call involves something of type `T`, so it puts off resolving the symbol until *phase 2*, when the template is instantiated.

---

Besides the `struct`s that you apparently copied out of a C header file, as mentioned by Cris, you also have

`typedef BYTE GrayScale;`

Don't use `typedef` anymore, at all.  For type alises, use `using`.  And we have `std::byte` which is not spelled in all caps, so don't declare your own.

`using GrayScale = std::byte;`

Comment: `std::byte` doesn’t implement arithmetic, which would make it hard to use as a pixel value (which is how I presume OP would use it). `std::uint8_t` would be more suitable.