# Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++

Tags: c++, image, template, classes, variadic

This is a follow-up question for [Three dimensional data structure in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288593/231235). I am trying to implement multi-dimensional image data structure with variadic template functions. For example, `image.at(4, 3)` is to access the element at location x = 4 and y = 3 in two dimensional case. In three dimensional case, `image.at(4, 3, 2)` is to access the element at location x = 4, y = 3 and z = 2. In this way, both constructing new image and accessing elements are easy.

**The experimental implementation**

- `Image` Class Implementation

  ```
  //  image.h
  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      template <typename ElementT>
      class Image
      {
      public:
          Image() = default;

          Image(const std::size_t width, const std::size_t height):
              image_data(width * height)
              {
                  size.reserve(2);
                  size.emplace_back(width);
                  size.emplace_back(height);
              }

          Image(const std::size_t width, const std::size_t height, const std::size_t depth):
              image_data(width * height * depth)
              {
                  size.reserve(3);
                  size.emplace_back(width);
                  size.emplace_back(height);
                  size.emplace_back(depth);
              }

          Image(const std::size_t x, const std::size_t y, const std::size_t z, const std::size_t w):
              image_data(x * y * z * w)
              {
                  size.reserve(4);
                  size.emplace_back(x);
                  size.emplace_back(y);
                  size.emplace_back(z);
                  size.emplace_back(w);
              }

          Image(const std::size_t a, const std::size_t b, const std::size_t c, const std::size_t d, const std::size_t e):
              image_data(a * b * c * d * e)
              {
                  size.reserve(5);
                  size.emplace_back(a);
                  size.emplace_back(b);
                  size.emplace_back(c);
                  size.emplace_back(d);
                  size.emplace_back(e);
              }

          Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(newWidth);
              size.emplace_back(newHeight);
              if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
              }
              image_data = input;
          }

          Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(newWidth);
              size.emplace_back(newHeight);
              if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
              }
              image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
          }

          Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
              size.emplace_back(input.size());
              for (auto& rows : input)
              {
                  image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
              }
              return;
          }

          template<typename... Args>
          constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
          {
              checkBoundary(indexInput...);
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              if constexpr (n == 2)
              {
                  auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[y * size[0] + x];
              }
              else if constexpr (n == 3)
              {
                  auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[(z * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
              }
              else if constexpr (n == 4)
              {
                  auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                  auto w = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[((w * size[2] + z) * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
              }
              else if constexpr (n == 5)
              {
                  auto a = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto b = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  auto c = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                  auto d = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                  auto e = get_from_variadic_template<5>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[(((e * size[3] + d) * size[2] + c) * size[1] + b) * size[0] + a];
              }
          }

          template<typename... Args>
          constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
          {
              checkBoundary(indexInput...);
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              if constexpr (n == 2)
              {
                  auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[y * size[0] + x];
              }
              else if constexpr (n == 3)
              {
                  auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[(z * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
              }
              else if constexpr (n == 4)
              {
                  auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                  auto w = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[((w * size[2] + z) * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
              }
              else if constexpr (n == 5)
              {
                  auto a = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                  auto b = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                  auto c = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                  auto d = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                  auto e = get_from_variadic_template<5>(indexInput...);
                  return image_data[(((e * size[3] + d) * size[2] + c) * size[1] + b) * size[0] + a];
              }
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
          {
              return size.size();
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
          {
              return size[0];
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
          {
              return size[1];
          }

          constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
          {
              return size;
          }

          std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

          void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
          {
              if(size.size() == 2)
              {
                  for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                  {
                      for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                      {
                          //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                          os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                      }
                      os << "\n";
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              else if (size.size() == 3)
              {
                  for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                  {
                      for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                      {
                          for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                          {
                              //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                              os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                          }
                          os << "\n";
                      }
                      os << "\n";
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
          }

          //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
          void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
          requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
          {
              for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
              {
                  for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                  {
                      os << "( ";
                      for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                      {
                          //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                          os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                      }
                      os << ")" << separator;
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              os << "\n";
              return;
          }

          void setAllValue(const ElementT input)
          {
              std::fill(image_data.begin(), image_data.end(), input);
          }

          friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              const std::string separator = "\t";
              rhs.print(separator, os);
              return os;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

          friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

          friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
          {
              return input1 += input2;
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
          {
              return input1 -= input2;
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
          {
              return multiplies(input1, input2);
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
          {
              return multiplies(input2, input1);
          }

  #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

          void Save(std::string filename)
          {
              const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
              //    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
              std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
              boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
              //    write class instance to archive
              ArchiveOut << *this;
              //    archive and stream closed when destructors are called
              ofs.close();
          }

  #endif
      private:
          std::vector<std::size_t> size;
          std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

          template<typename... Args>
          void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
          {
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              if constexpr (n == 2)
              {
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given x out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given y out of range!");
              }
              if constexpr (n == 3)
              {
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given x out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given y out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...) >= size[2])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given z out of range!");
              }
              if constexpr (n == 4)
              {
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...) >= size[2])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...) >= size[3])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
              }
              if constexpr (n == 5)
              {
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...) >= size[2])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...) >= size[3])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                  if (get_from_variadic_template<5>(indexInput...) >= size[4])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
              }
          }
      };

      template<typename T, typename ElementT>
      concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

The full testing code:

```
//  Three dimensional data structure in C++
//  Developed by Jimmy Hu

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>      //  for assert
#include <chrono>       //  for std::chrono::system_clock::now
#include <cmath>        //  for std::exp
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>    //  for std::is_execution_policy_v
#include <iostream>     //  for std::cout
#include <vector>

struct RGB
{
    std::uint8_t channels[3];
};

using GrayScale = std::uint8_t;

namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  recursive_depth function implementation
    template<typename T>
    constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
    {
        return std::size_t{0};
    }

    template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
    constexpr std::size_t recursive_depth()
    {
        return recursive_depth<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>>() + std::size_t{1};
    }

    template<std::size_t index = 1, typename Arg, typename... Args>
    constexpr static auto& get_from_variadic_template(const Arg& first, const Args&... inputs)
    {
        if constexpr (index > 1)
            return get_from_variadic_template<index - 1>(inputs...);
        else
            return first;
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr static auto& first_of(Args&... inputs) {
        return get_from_variadic_template<1>(inputs...);
    }

    template<std::size_t, typename, typename...>
    struct get_from_variadic_template_struct { };

    template<typename T1, typename... Ts>
    struct get_from_variadic_template_struct<1, T1, Ts...>
    {
        using type = T1;
    };

    template<std::size_t index, typename T1, typename... Ts>
    requires ( requires { typename get_from_variadic_template_struct<index - 1, Ts...>::type; })
    struct get_from_variadic_template_struct<index, T1, Ts...>
    {
        using type = typename get_from_variadic_template_struct<index - 1, Ts...>::type;
    };

    template<std::size_t index, typename... Ts>
    using get_from_variadic_template_t = typename get_from_variadic_template_struct<index, Ts...>::type;
}

//  image.h
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        Image(const std::size_t width, const std::size_t height):
            image_data(width * height)
            {
                size.reserve(2);
                size.emplace_back(width);
                size.emplace_back(height);
            }

        Image(const std::size_t width, const std::size_t height, const std::size_t depth):
            image_data(width * height * depth)
            {
                size.reserve(3);
                size.emplace_back(width);
                size.emplace_back(height);
                size.emplace_back(depth);
            }

        Image(const std::size_t x, const std::size_t y, const std::size_t z, const std::size_t w):
            image_data(x * y * z * w)
            {
                size.reserve(4);
                size.emplace_back(x);
                size.emplace_back(y);
                size.emplace_back(z);
                size.emplace_back(w);
            }

        Image(const std::size_t a, const std::size_t b, const std::size_t c, const std::size_t d, const std::size_t e):
            image_data(a * b * c * d * e)
            {
                size.reserve(5);
                size.emplace_back(a);
                size.emplace_back(b);
                size.emplace_back(c);
                size.emplace_back(d);
                size.emplace_back(e);
            }

        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = input;
        }

        Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            if constexpr (n == 2)
            {
                auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[y * size[0] + x];
            }
            else if constexpr (n == 3)
            {
                auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[(z * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
            }
            else if constexpr (n == 4)
            {
                auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                auto w = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[((w * size[2] + z) * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
            }
            else if constexpr (n == 5)
            {
                auto a = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto b = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                auto c = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                auto d = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                auto e = get_from_variadic_template<5>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[(((e * size[3] + d) * size[2] + c) * size[1] + b) * size[0] + a];
            }
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            if constexpr (n == 2)
            {
                auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[y * size[0] + x];
            }
            else if constexpr (n == 3)
            {
                auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[(z * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
            }
            else if constexpr (n == 4)
            {
                auto x = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto y = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                auto z = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                auto w = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[((w * size[2] + z) * size[1] + y) * size[0] + x];
            }
            else if constexpr (n == 5)
            {
                auto a = get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...);
                auto b = get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...);
                auto c = get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...);
                auto d = get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...);
                auto e = get_from_variadic_template<5>(indexInput...);
                return image_data[(((e * size[3] + d) * size[2] + c) * size[1] + b) * size[0] + a];
            }
        }
  
        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
        {
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    os << "( ";
                    for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                    }
                    os << ")" << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            os << "\n";
            return;
        }

        void setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(image_data.begin(), image_data.end(), input);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }
        
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //  write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //  archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }
        
#endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            if constexpr (n == 2)
            {
                if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given x out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given y out of range!");
            }
            if constexpr (n == 3)
            {
                if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given x out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given y out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...) >= size[2])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given z out of range!");
            }
            if constexpr (n == 4)
            {
                if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...) >= size[2])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...) >= size[3])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
            }
            if constexpr (n == 5)
            {
                if (get_from_variadic_template<1>(indexInput...) >= size[0])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<2>(indexInput...) >= size[1])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<3>(indexInput...) >= size[2])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<4>(indexInput...) >= size[3])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
                if (get_from_variadic_template<5>(indexInput...) >= size[4])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range!");
            }
        }
    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;
}

namespace TinyDIP
{
    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr bool is_width_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        return x.getWidth() == y.getWidth();
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr bool is_width_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y, const Image<ElementT>& z)
    {
        return is_width_same(x, y) && is_width_same(y, z) && is_width_same(x, z);
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr bool is_height_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        return x.getHeight() == y.getHeight();
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr bool is_height_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y, const Image<ElementT>& z)
    {
        return is_height_same(x, y) && is_height_same(y, z) && is_height_same(x, z);
    }
    
    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr bool is_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        return is_width_same(x, y) && is_height_same(x, y);
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr bool is_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y, const Image<ElementT>& z)
    {
        return is_size_same(x, y) && is_size_same(y, z) && is_size_same(x, z);
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void assert_width_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        assert(is_width_same(x, y));
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void assert_width_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y, const Image<ElementT>& z)
    {
        assert(is_width_same(x, y, z));
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void assert_height_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        assert(is_height_same(x, y));
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void assert_height_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y, const Image<ElementT>& z)
    {
        assert(is_height_same(x, y, z));
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void assert_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        assert_width_same(x, y);
        assert_height_same(x, y);
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void assert_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y, const Image<ElementT>& z)
    {
        assert_size_same(x, y);
        assert_size_same(y, z);
        assert_size_same(x, z);
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_width_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        if (!is_width_same(x, y))
            throw std::runtime_error("Width mismatched!");
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_height_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        if (!is_height_same(x, y))
            throw std::runtime_error("Height mismatched!");
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        check_width_same(x, y);
        check_height_same(x, y);
    }
}

template<typename ElementT>
void multidimensionalImageTest(const size_t size = 3)
{
    std::cout << "Test with 2D image:\n";
    auto image2d = TinyDIP::Image<ElementT>(size, size);
    image2d.setAllValue(1);
    image2d.at(1, 1) = 3;
    image2d.print();
    std::cout << "Test with 3D image:\n";
    auto image3d = TinyDIP::Image<double>(size, size, size);
    image3d.setAllValue(0);
    image3d.at(0, 0, 0) = 4;
    image3d.print();
    return;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    multidimensionalImageTest<double>();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the test code above:

```
Test with 2D image:
1   1   1   
1   3   1   
1   1   1   

Test with 3D image:
4   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   

0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   

0   0   0   
0   0   0   
0   0   0   


Computation finished at Sat Dec 30 11:10:29 2023
elapsed time: 0.00150394
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/KoKbsYET9)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Three dimensional data structure in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288593/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to create multi-dimensional image data structure with variadic template functions in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Despite the usage of `Image` class is easy and the feasible  (dimensionality of an `Image` object can be changed in run-time), there are several `if constexpr` blocks to deal with various dimension case. Is there any better way to improve the implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Allow 1D images

One-dimensional images are not that uncommon in computer graphics. There is no reason why your class couldn't be made to support them.

## Make the constructors generic

Instead of having 4 different constructors that take different numbers of sizes, create a generic constructor:

```
template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
Image(Sizes... sizes): image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
{
    size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
    (size.push_back(sizes), ...);
}
```

Although you can write this even more simply as:

```
template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
{}
```

Now you can also see that you can make a generic one that takes a vector of elements of arbitrary dimensions as well. And if we want to be really generic, allow any range of elements:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
         std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
    size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
{
    if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
    }
}
```

## Make everything work for more than 5 dimensions

I can see why you stopped at 5 dimensions if you still have to manually write the code for each number of dimensions separately. Just spend a little bit of time to figure out how to write this in a generic way, then you'll actually have to do less typing and make the code work for *any* number of dimensions.

Whenever you have to loop over a parameter pack, you can always do this:

```
auto function = [&](auto index) {
    …
};

(function(indexInput), …);
```

Now `function()` will be called for every element in `indexInput` in succession. In that lambda you can do anything you want, including incrementing a loop counter. So use that to build up the index you need to read from `image_data`. This is left as an excercise for the reader.

## Consider making the number of dimensions a template argument

With your current implementation, an object of type `Image` can have any number of dimensions, but it's not known at compile time. But you have added runtime checks to verify that you pass the right number of arguments to `at()` for example. Instead of doing this at runtime, it might be better to be able to do the checks at compile time, by making the number of dimensions part of the type:

```
template<std::size_t Rank>
class Image {
    …
    std::array<std::size_t, Rank> size;
};
```

Then you can also use concepts to restrict the number of arguments allowed:

```
template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
requires (sizeof...(Sizes) == Rank)
Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
{}
```

And to avoid having to explicitly specify the number of dimensions when creating an `Image<>`, you can use a deduction guide:

```
template<typename... Sizes>
requires (sizeof...(Sizes) == Rank)
Image(Sizes... sizes) -> Image<sizeof...(sizes)>;
```

And of course do the same for the constructor that also takes a range of elements as input.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In the **Make the constructors generic** part, is the allocation of `image_data` missing in the generic constructor?

Comment: Yes I forgot that, I fixed it.

Comment: Shouldn't the deduction guide be constrained to `std::same_as<std::size_t>` too?