Image Rotation with Shear Transformation in C++
This is a follow-up question for Image Rotation and Transpose Functions Implementation in C++ and An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++. I am trying to implement another image rotation function with shear transformation in this post. As another approach, the function is named rotate_detail_shear_transformation and I keep rotate_detail with trigonometric function ways for learning purpose. The example output:



Image Input
Output









The experimental implementation

rotate_detail_shear_transformation template functions implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  rotate_detail_shear_transformation template function implementation
    //  rotate_detail_shear_transformation template function performs image rotation
    //  Reference: https://gautamnagrawal.medium.com/rotating-image-by-any-angle-shear-transformation-using-only-numpy-d28d16eb5076
    template<arithmetic ElementT, std::floating_point FloatingType = double>
    constexpr static auto rotate_detail_shear_transformation(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType radians)
    {
        if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
        }
        radians = std::fmod(radians, 2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double>);
        //  if negative degrees
        if(radians < 0)
        {
            radians = radians + 2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double>;
        }
        //  if 0° rotation case
        if (radians == 0)
        {
            return input;
        }
        //  if 90° rotation case
        if(radians == std::numbers::pi_v<long double> / 2.0)
        {
            Image<ElementT> output(input.getHeight(), input.getWidth());
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
                {
                    output.at(input.getHeight() - y - 1, x) = 
                        input.at(x, y);
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
        auto cosine = std::cos(radians);
        auto sine = std::sin(radians);
        auto height = input.getHeight();
        auto width = input.getWidth();
        FloatingType original_centre_width  = std::round((static_cast<FloatingType>(width) + 1.0) / 2.0 - 1.0);
        FloatingType original_centre_height = std::round((static_cast<FloatingType>(height) + 1.0) / 2.0 - 1.0);

        //  Define the height and width of the new image that is to be formed
        auto new_height = std::round(std::abs(height*cosine) + std::abs(width*sine)) + 1;
        auto new_width = std::round(std::abs(width*cosine) + std::abs(height*sine)) + 1;

        //  Define another image variable of dimensions of new_height and new _column filled with zeros
        Image<ElementT> output(static_cast<std::size_t>(new_width), static_cast<std::size_t>(new_height));

        //  Find the centre of the new image that will be obtained
        FloatingType new_centre_width  = std::round((static_cast<FloatingType>(new_width) + 1.0) / 2.0 - 1.0);
        FloatingType new_centre_height = std::round((static_cast<FloatingType>(new_height) + 1.0) / 2.0 - 1.0);

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.getHeight(); ++i)
        {
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < input.getWidth(); ++j)
            {
                //  co-ordinates of pixel with respect to the centre of original image
                auto y = height - 1.0 - i - original_centre_height;
                auto x = width - 1.0 - j - original_centre_width;

                //  co-ordinate of pixel with respect to the rotated image
                auto new_y = std::round(-x * sine + y * cosine);
                auto new_x = std::round(x * cosine + y * sine);

                /*  since image will be rotated the centre will change too, 
                    so to adust to that we will need to change new_x and new_y with respect to the new centre*/
                new_y = new_centre_height - new_y;
                new_x = new_centre_width - new_x;
                if((0 <= new_x) && (new_x < new_width) &&
                   (0 <= new_y) && (new_y < new_height))
                {
                    output.at(
                    static_cast<std::size_t>(new_x),
                    static_cast<std::size_t>(new_y)) = 
                    input.at(j, i);
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    //  rotate_detail_shear_transformation template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, class FloatingType = double>
    requires ((std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>) || (std::same_as<ElementT, HSV>))       //  TODO: Create a base class for both RGB and HSV
    constexpr static auto rotate_detail_shear_transformation(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType radians)
    {
        if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
        }
        return apply_each(input, [&](auto&& planes) { return rotate_detail_shear_transformation(planes, radians); });
    }
}


Image class implementation (in file image.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.push_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                 std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
        {
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    os << "( ";
                    for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                    }
                    os << ")" << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            os << "\n";
            return;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }

#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //    write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //    archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }

#endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }
#endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;
}


#endif



The usage of rotate function:
std::string file_path = "InputImages/1";
auto bmp1 = TinyDIP::bmp_read(file_path.c_str(), false);
bmp1 = TinyDIP::rotate_detail_shear_transformation(bmp1, 1.0);
TinyDIP::bmp_write("test", bmp1);

TinyDIP on GitHub
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
Image Rotation and Transpose Functions Implementation in C++ and
An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to implement image rotation with shear transformation in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please review the implementation of rotate_detail_shear_transformation template functions.



Rotation without rotating. by Matt Parker YouTube

You have obvious color averaging issues. There are obvious artifacts in the rotated image. If you are using the obvious color averaging technique this is probably the cause. See here for a better technique. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw&t=2s

If memory servies me: bad => RGB = {(R1+R2)/2, (G1+G2)/2, (B1+B2)/2} Good => RGB = { SQRT(R1^2 + R2^2)/2, SQRT(G1^2 + G2^2)/2, SQRT(B1^2 + B2^2)/2}

Normally, people fill in the new image by iterating over each element of the target image and figuring out its source point. Otherwise, you end up with various problems of skipping points and having multiple source points match the same target point. Of course, for efficiency purposes, you should add fast filters to sift out-bounds points.
