Two Dimensional Discrete Fourier Transform Template Function Implementation for Image in C++
This is a follow-up question for An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++. For learning purpose, I am trying to implement two dimensional discrete fourier transform template function dft2 and inverse discrete fourier transform template function idft2 in this post.
The experimental implementation

dft2 template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  two dimensional discrete fourier transform template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, typename ComplexType = std::complex<long double>>
    requires(std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT>)
    constexpr auto dft2(const Image<ElementT>& input)
    {
        auto output = Image<ComplexType>(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
        auto normalization_factor = std::sqrt(1.0 / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth() * input.getHeight()));
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
        {
            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
            {
                long double sum_real = 0.0;
                long double sum_imag = 0.0; 
                for (std::size_t n = 0; n < input.getHeight(); ++n)
                {
                    for (std::size_t m = 0; m < input.getWidth(); ++m)
                    {
                        sum_real += input.at_without_boundary_check(m, n) * 
                            std::cos(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight())));
                        sum_imag += -input.at_without_boundary_check(m, n) * 
                            std::sin(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight())));
                    }
                }
                output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y).real(normalization_factor * sum_real);
                output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y).imag(normalization_factor * sum_imag);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}


idft2 template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  two dimensional inverse discrete fourier transform template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, typename ComplexType = std::complex<long double>>
    constexpr auto idft2(const Image<ElementT>& input)
    {
        auto output = Image<ComplexType>(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
        auto normalization_factor = std::sqrt(1.0 / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth() * input.getHeight()));
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
        {
            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
            {
                std::complex<long double> sum = 0.0;
                std::complex<long double> i (0.0,1.0);
                for (std::size_t n = 0; n < input.getHeight(); ++n)
                {
                    for (std::size_t m = 0; m < input.getWidth(); ++m)
                    {
                        sum += input.at_without_boundary_check(m, n) * 
                            (std::cos(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight()))) +
                            i * std::sin(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight()))));
                    }
                }
                output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y) = normalization_factor * sum;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}


Image class implementation (in file image.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.push_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                    std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
        requires(std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>, ElementT>)
        Image(Range&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  at without boundary check
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at_without_boundary_check(indexInput...));
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }

    #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //    write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //    archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }

    #endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

    #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }

    #endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;
}



Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  Two Dimensional Discrete Fourier Transform Template Function Implementation for Image in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

//  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264642/6667035
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) \
    M_Assert_Helper(#Expr, Expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, Msg)
#else
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) ;
#endif

void M_Assert_Helper(const char* expr_str, bool expr, const char* file, int line, std::string msg)
{
    if (!expr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Assert failed:\t" << msg << "\n"
            << "Expected:\t" << expr_str << "\n"
            << "Source:\t\t" << file << ", line " << line << "\n";
        abort();
    }
}

struct recursive_print_fn
{
    template<std::ranges::input_range T>
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& input, const int level = 0) const
    {
        T output = input;
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
            [&](auto&& x)
            {
                std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
                return x;
            }
        );
        return output;
    }

    template<std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& input, const int level = 0) const
    {
        T output = input;
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
            [&](auto&& element)
            {
                return operator()(element, level + 1);
            }
        );
        return output;
    }
};

inline constexpr recursive_print_fn recursive_print;

namespace TinyDIP
{
    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.push_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                    std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
        requires(std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<Range>, ElementT>)
        Image(Range&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  at without boundary check
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at_without_boundary_check(indexInput...));
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                    std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }
        
    #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //  write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //  archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }
        
    #endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

    #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }
        
    #endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;

    //  two dimensional discrete fourier transform template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, typename ComplexType = std::complex<long double>>
    requires(std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT>)
    constexpr auto dft2(const Image<ElementT>& input)
    {
        auto output = Image<ComplexType>(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
        auto normalization_factor = std::sqrt(1.0 / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth() * input.getHeight()));
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
        {
            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
            {
                long double sum_real = 0.0;
                long double sum_imag = 0.0; 
                for (std::size_t n = 0; n < input.getHeight(); ++n)
                {
                    for (std::size_t m = 0; m < input.getWidth(); ++m)
                    {
                        sum_real += input.at_without_boundary_check(m, n) * 
                            std::cos(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight())));
                        sum_imag += -input.at_without_boundary_check(m, n) * 
                            std::sin(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight())));
                    }
                }
                output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y).real(normalization_factor * sum_real);
                output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y).imag(normalization_factor * sum_imag);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    //  two dimensional inverse discrete fourier transform template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, typename ComplexType = std::complex<long double>>
    constexpr auto idft2(const Image<ElementT>& input)
    {
        auto output = Image<ComplexType>(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
        auto normalization_factor = std::sqrt(1.0 / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth() * input.getHeight()));
        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
        {
            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
            {
                std::complex<long double> sum = 0.0;
                std::complex<long double> i (0.0,1.0);
                for (std::size_t n = 0; n < input.getHeight(); ++n)
                {
                    for (std::size_t m = 0; m < input.getWidth(); ++m)
                    {
                        sum += input.at_without_boundary_check(m, n) * 
                            (std::cos(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight()))) +
                            i * std::sin(2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> * (x * m / static_cast<long double>(input.getWidth()) + y * n / static_cast<long double>(input.getHeight()))));
                    }
                }
                output.at_without_boundary_check(x, y) = normalization_factor * sum;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    TinyDIP::Image<double> I1(5, 5);
    for(std::size_t y = 0; y < I1.getHeight(); ++y)
    {
        for(std::size_t x = 0; x < I1.getWidth(); ++x)
        {
            I1.at(x, y) = y * I1.getWidth() + x + 1;
        }
    }
    I1.print();
    auto output = dft2(I1);
    output.print();
    auto inverse_output = idft2(output);
    inverse_output.print();

    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return 0;
}

The output of the test code above:
1   2   3   4   5   
6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25  

(65,0)  (-2.5,3.44095)  (-2.5,0.812299) (-2.5,-0.812299)    (-2.5,-3.44095) 
(-12.5,17.2048) (-6.93889e-18,3.64292e-18)  (-5.55112e-18,3.81639e-18)  (2.86229e-18,9.36751e-18)   (0,6.66699e-18) 
(-12.5,4.0615)  (-5.55112e-18,4.33681e-18)  (-1.9082e-18,5.20417e-18)   (6.93889e-19,9.09561e-18)   (7.97973e-18,6.93889e-18)   
(-12.5,-4.0615) (4.94396e-18,1.14492e-17)   (3.1225e-18,1.22181e-17)    (-1.47451e-18,3.46945e-18)  (9.36751e-18,1.75207e-17)   
(-12.5,-17.2048)    (1.73472e-18,1.11773e-17)   (1.05818e-17,9.36751e-18)   (7.28584e-18,1.66533e-17)   (2.56739e-17,1.249e-17) 

(1,4.15096e-17) (2,-7.60747e-18)    (3,-5.66242e-18)    (4,2.60766e-18) (5,7.31655e-18) 
(6,-1.03984e-17)    (7,6.71039e-18) (8,1.03952e-17) (9,8.44476e-18) (10,3.73766e-19)    
(11,-5.38253e-18)   (12,9.11608e-18)    (13,5.87473e-18)    (14,-4.95731e-18)   (15,-2.91624e-18)   
(16,2.66048e-18)    (17,9.70311e-18)    (18,-8.76072e-19)   (19,3.44742e-20)    (20,-4.5831e-18)    
(21,1.05554e-17)    (22,1.1901e-19) (23,-2.01196e-18)   (24,-8.29799e-18)   (25,-4.61452e-18)   

Computation finished at Mon May 27 15:09:59 2024
elapsed time: 0.000580614

Godbolt link is here.
TinyDIP on GitHub
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to implement two dimensional discrete fourier transform template function dft2 and inverse discrete fourier transform template function idft2 in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please review the implementation of dft2 and idft2 template functions and its tests.



Looks fine, not much to comment. Obviously this is a very slow algorithm, but you already knew that. I would add a dependency on pocketfft in your project. If does fast FFTs of any length, and is pretty fast, considering how small the code base is. The FFT is not something I’d try implementing from scratch. (Pocketfft is used by SciPy and NumPy for their FFT functions, and I use it in DIPlib too.)

Actually, looking again at your code, it seems you didn’t implement the DFT sum separably. This means you can both simplify and speed up your code without introducing an FFT (of course it won’t be nearly as fast as using an FFT, but it’ll be faster than what you have now). You should write a function that does a 1D DFT, then apply it to each row of the image, and on that result apply it to each column. You now compute that line of code inside your loops H^2 x W^2 times. When separable, you will apply it H x W^2 + W x H^2 times. You’ll go from O(n^4) to O(n^3) for an nxn image.
