convn Template Function Implementation for Image in C++
This is a follow-up question for conv2 Template Function Implementation for Image in C++ and conv3 Template Function Implementation for Image in C++. I am trying to perform n-dimensional convolution convn like Matlab in this post.
The experimental implementation

convn template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  convn template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT>
    requires(std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT> || is_complex<ElementT>::value)
    constexpr static auto convn(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        return convn(std::execution::seq, x, y);
    }

    //  convn template function implementation (with Execution Policy)
    template<class ExecutionPolicy, typename ElementT>
    requires((std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>) &&
             (std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT> || is_complex<ElementT>::value))
    constexpr static auto convn(ExecutionPolicy&& execution_policy, const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        std::vector<std::size_t> output_size;
        auto xsize = x.getSize();
        auto ysize = y.getSize();
        std::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(xsize),
            std::ranges::cend(xsize),
            std::ranges::cbegin(ysize),
            std::back_inserter(output_size),
            [](auto input1, auto input2) { return input1 + input2 - 1; });
        std::vector<ElementT> data;
        data.resize(
            std::reduce(
                execution_policy,
                std::ranges::cbegin(output_size),
                std::ranges::cend(output_size),
                1,
                std::multiplies<>{}));
        Image<ElementT> output(data, output_size);
        impl::convn_detail(x, y, output, xsize.size() - 1);
        return output;
    }
}


convn_detail template function implementation (in file image_operations.h)
namespace TinyDIP
{
    namespace impl {
        //  convn_detail template function implementation
        template<typename ElementT>
        requires(std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT> || is_complex<ElementT>::value)
        constexpr static void convn_detail(
                    const Image<ElementT>& x,
                    const Image<ElementT>& y,
                    Image<ElementT>& output,
                    std::size_t level = 0,
                    std::size_t index1 = 0,
                    std::size_t index2 = 0,
                    std::size_t index3 = 0)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < y.getSize(level); ++i)
            {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < x.getSize(level); ++j)
                {
                    index1 += (i + j) * output.getStride(level);
                    index2 += j * x.getStride(level);
                    index3 += i * y.getStride(level);
                    if(level == 0)
                    {
                        output.set(index1) = 
                                output.get(index1) +
                                x.get(index2) *
                                y.get(index3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        convn_detail(x, y, output, level - 1, index1, index2, index3);
                    }
                    index1 -= (i + j) * output.getStride(level);
                    index2 -= j * x.getStride(level);
                    index3 -= i * y.getStride(level);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  convn Template Function Implementation for Image in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

//  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264642/6667035
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) \
    M_Assert_Helper(#Expr, Expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, Msg)
#else
#   define M_Assert(Expr, Msg) ;
#endif

void M_Assert_Helper(const char* expr_str, bool expr, const char* file, int line, std::string msg)
{
    if (!expr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Assert failed:\t" << msg << "\n"
            << "Expected:\t" << expr_str << "\n"
            << "Source:\t\t" << file << ", line " << line << "\n";
        abort();
    }
}

struct recursive_print_fn
{
    template<std::ranges::input_range T>
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& input, const int level = 0) const
    {
        T output = input;
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
            [&](auto&& x)
            {
                std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << x << std::endl;
                return x;
            }
        );
        return output;
    }

    template<std::ranges::input_range T>
    requires (std::ranges::input_range<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>)
    constexpr auto operator()(const T& input, const int level = 0) const
    {
        T output = input;
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(input), std::ranges::cend(input), std::ranges::begin(output),
            [&](auto&& element)
            {
                return operator()(element, level + 1);
            }
        );
        return output;
    }
};

inline constexpr recursive_print_fn recursive_print;

struct RGB
{
    std::uint8_t channels[3];
};

struct RGB_DOUBLE
{
    double channels[3];
};

using GrayScale = std::uint8_t;

struct HSV
{
    double channels[3];    //  Range: 0 <= H < 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 255
};

namespace TinyDIP
{
    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.emplace_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                 std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data = std::move(input);
            auto count = std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(sizes), std::ranges::cend(sizes), 1, std::multiplies());
            if (image_data.size() != count) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }


        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  at_without_boundary_check template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at_without_boundary_check(indexInput...));
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  get function implementation
        constexpr ElementT get(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set function implementation
        constexpr ElementT& set(const std::size_t index) noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  cast template function implementation
        template<typename TargetT>
        constexpr Image<TargetT> cast()
        {
            std::vector<TargetT> output_data;
            output_data.resize(image_data.size());
            std::transform(
                std::ranges::cbegin(image_data),
                std::ranges::cend(image_data),
                std::ranges::begin(output_data),
                [](auto& input){ return static_cast<TargetT>(input); }
                );
            Image<TargetT> output(output_data, size);
            return output;
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }
  
        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize() const noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return size[index];
        }

        //  getStride function implementation
        constexpr std::size_t getStride(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            if(index == 0)
            {
                return std::size_t{1};
            }
            std::size_t output = std::size_t{1};
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            {
                output *= size[i];
            }
            return output;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 4)
            {
                for(std::size_t a = 0; a < size[3]; ++a)
                {
                    os << "group = " << a << "\n";
                    for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                        {
                            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                            {
                                //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                                os << +at(x, y, z, a) << separator;
                            }
                            os << "\n";
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
        {
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    os << "( ";
                    for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                    }
                    os << ")" << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            os << "\n";
            return;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }
        
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //  write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //  archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }
        
#endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }
#endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;

    //  zeros template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto zeros(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = Image<ElementT>(sizes...);
        return output;
    }

    //  ones template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto ones(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = zeros<ElementT>(sizes...);
        output.setAllValue(1);
        return output;
    }

    namespace impl {
        //  convn_detail template function implementation
        template<typename ElementT>
        requires(std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT> || is_complex<ElementT>::value)
        constexpr static void convn_detail(
                    const Image<ElementT>& x,
                    const Image<ElementT>& y,
                    Image<ElementT>& output,
                    std::size_t level = 0,
                    std::size_t index1 = 0,
                    std::size_t index2 = 0,
                    std::size_t index3 = 0)
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < y.getSize(level); ++i)
            {
                for (std::size_t j = 0; j < x.getSize(level); ++j)
                {
                    index1 += (i + j) * output.getStride(level);
                    index2 += j * x.getStride(level);
                    index3 += i * y.getStride(level);
                    if(level == 0)
                    {
                        output.set(index1) = 
                                output.get(index1) +
                                x.get(index2) *
                                y.get(index3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        convn_detail(x, y, output, level - 1, index1, index2, index3);
                    }
                    index1 -= (i + j) * output.getStride(level);
                    index2 -= j * x.getStride(level);
                    index3 -= i * y.getStride(level);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //  convn template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT>
    requires(std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT> || is_complex<ElementT>::value)
    constexpr static auto convn(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        return convn(std::execution::seq, x, y);
    }

    //  convn template function implementation (with Execution Policy)
    template<class ExecutionPolicy, typename ElementT>
    requires((std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>) &&
             (std::floating_point<ElementT> || std::integral<ElementT> || is_complex<ElementT>::value))
    constexpr static auto convn(ExecutionPolicy&& execution_policy, const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        std::vector<std::size_t> output_size;
        auto xsize = x.getSize();
        auto ysize = y.getSize();
        std::transform(
            std::ranges::cbegin(xsize),
            std::ranges::cend(xsize),
            std::ranges::cbegin(ysize),
            std::back_inserter(output_size),
            [](auto input1, auto input2) { return input1 + input2 - 1; });
        std::vector<ElementT> data;
        data.resize(
            std::reduce(
                execution_policy,
                std::ranges::cbegin(output_size),
                std::ranges::cend(output_size),
                1,
                std::multiplies<>{}));
        Image<ElementT> output(data, output_size);
        impl::convn_detail(x, y, output, xsize.size() - 1);
        return output;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto image1 = TinyDIP::ones<double>(std::size_t{2}, std::size_t{3}, std::size_t{2}, std::size_t{2});
    TinyDIP::convn(image1, image1).print();
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << '\n';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The output of the test code above:
group = 0
1   2   1   
2   4   2   
3   6   3   
2   4   2   
1   2   1   

2   4   2   
4   8   4   
6   12  6   
4   8   4   
2   4   2   

1   2   1   
2   4   2   
3   6   3   
2   4   2   
1   2   1   


group = 1
2   4   2   
4   8   4   
6   12  6   
4   8   4   
2   4   2   

4   8   4   
8   16  8   
12  24  12  
8   16  8   
4   8   4   

2   4   2   
4   8   4   
6   12  6   
4   8   4   
2   4   2   


group = 2
1   2   1   
2   4   2   
3   6   3   
2   4   2   
1   2   1   

2   4   2   
4   8   4   
6   12  6   
4   8   4   
2   4   2   

1   2   1   
2   4   2   
3   6   3   
2   4   2   
1   2   1   



Computation finished at Tue Jul 23 05:40:39 2024
elapsed time: 0.000145431

Godbolt link is here.
TinyDIP on GitHub
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
conv2 Template Function Implementation for Image in C++ and
conv3 Template Function Implementation for Image in C++

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to implement n-dimensional convolution convn like Matlab in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please review the implementation of convn template function and its tests.



Naming things
Toby Speight already pointed out that using x and y for the names of images is confusing, as those names are typically used for the x and y dimensions. Consider using image and kernel instead.
Since your Image class already handles an arbitrary number of dimensions, I don't see any point in having separate conv2(), conv3() and convn(). Just have one function that handles arbitrary convolutions. And since you should also avoid unnecessary abbreviations, I recommend you name it convolve() instead.
Also think about the indices i, j and index1…index3. It's really hard to tell from their names what they mean. I would make sure that it's at least clear from the names whether they are related to the input image, the input kernel or the output image.
Make better use of the ranges library
You are already using the ranges library, but strangely enough you are using cbegin() and cend() in lots of places, when one of the nice features of ranges algorithms is that you don't need two iterators anymore. So for example, creating output_size() can be done like so:
std::vector<std::size_t> output_size;
std::ranges::transform(
    x.getSize(),
    y.getSize(),
    std::back_inserter(output_size),
    [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return lhs + rhs - 1; }
);

Or making even more use of C++23:
auto output_size =
    std::views::zip_transform(
        [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return lhs + rhs - 1; },
        x.getSize(),
        y.getSize()
    ) | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();

Add a constructor for Image that takes only a vector of sizes
Note how you had to create a vector data, which could be rather large, just to construct the output? The contents of data is copied but overwritten later. That's a lot of wasted CPU cycles. Consider creating a constructor that only takes a vector of sizes as input. That will be more efficient and will simplify your convolution functions.
Reconsider your constraints
Your convolution function constrains the possible inputs a lot: only integers, floating points and complex numbers are allowed as element types, and the input image and convolution kernel have to use the same element type. However, the only actual restriction you have is that an element of the input image can be multiplied by an element of the convolution kernel. And in fact, that's only because you hardcode the use of the operator *.
The problem is that you can't convolve an image of floats with a kernel of doubles, or an RGB image with a greyscale kernel. To lift these restrictions, allow the caller to override the per-element operation (which can default to std::multiplies), and relax the constraint to checking that this per-element operation is valid for the input image and kernel. So:
template<class ExecutionPolicy, typename ImageT, typename KernelT,
         typename F = std::multiplies<std::common_type_t<ImageT, KernelT>>>
requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>
         && std::regular_invocable<F, ImageT, KernelT>)
constexpr auto convolution(ExecutionPolicy&& execution_policy,
                           const Image<ImageT>& image,
                           const Image<KernelT>& kernel,
                           F f = {})
{
    …
    impl::convolution_detail(x, y, output, xsize.size() - 1, f);
    …
)
…
template<typename ImageT, typename KernelT,
         typename F = std::multiplies<std::common_type_t<ImageT, KernelT>>
requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>
         && std::regular_invocable<F, ImageT, KernelT>)
constexpr auto convolution_detail(…, F f = {})
{
    …
    output.set(output_index) =
        output.get(output_index)
        + std::invoke(f, image.get(image_index), kernel.get(kernel_index));
    …
)

The execution policy is useless
The only thing that is potentially parallelized in your code is the compution of the size of data, but I doubt you'll ever have such a high number of dimensions that this will be of any benefit. The actual convolution is always single-threaded.
It's not trivial to find the best way to parallelize the convolution algorithm; it depends on the size of each dimension what the best strategy is. However, you could start by naively parallelizing the outermost for-loop at the outermost recursion level.

> I don't see any point in having separate conv2(), conv3() and convn() I am trying to mimic Matlab's convolution function. Matlab has both conv2 and convn functions.

Sure, but do you really need to follow Matlab's naming convention? Does it fit with the other functions you've added to your TinyDIP library over time?

> Also think about the indices i, j and index1…index3. Any suggestion about those names?

Continuing G. Sliepen’s answer:
Another strange name is level, it indicates which image dimension the loop works over. It has nothing to do with levels. dimension would be more appropriate, and would make the code easier to understand.
You iterate over the two size arrays (image and kernel) using the size of the image size array. If the kernel has fewer dimensions, you’ll be reading out of bounds. Check your implied assumptions!
I’m worried that the recursive process is going to blow up your stack. For an image of size XxYxZ, the implementation function calls itself Y*Z times, which can be a lot. Have you tried this with a relatively large 3D image? The recursion depth is only 3 for a 3D image, it will not blow up the stack.
Finally, I would expect the test suite to compute a 2D convolution and compare the result with conv2, then a 3D convolution and compare the result with conv3. If it works correctly for 2D and 3D images, it is highly unlikely to not work correctly for the 4D case.

> Another strange name is level I think that level indicate recursion_level

> I’m worried that the recursive process is going to blow up your stack. Is there any better way to address this issue?

@JimmyHu Ah, I see where you're coming from. With "level" I think of pyramid level. Yes, it is the recursion level, but it represents the image dimension.

@JimmyHu I was wrong to worry about the stack, the recursion depth is not Y*Z, it's just 3. Still, a function calling itself recursively inside a loop means that there are lots and lots of function calls that will slow down execution. This comment doesn't give a whole lot of details, but it does point you to the solution for an nD loop without recursion: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293031/conv3-template-function-implementation-for-image-in-c#comment583646_293031
