two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation in C++
This is a follow-up question for euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for Image in C++. To avoid two unnecessary temporary images in the previous version of code, a new two_input_map_reduce template function is proposed.
The experimental implementation

two_input_map_reduce template function implementation
//  two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation
template<
    class ExecutionPolicy,
    std::ranges::input_range Input1,
    std::ranges::input_range Input2,
    class T,
    class BinaryOp1 = std::minus<T>,
    class BinaryOp2 = std::plus<T>
>
requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>)
constexpr auto two_input_map_reduce(
    ExecutionPolicy execution_policy,
    const Input1& input1,
    const Input2& input2,
    const T init = {},
    const BinaryOp1& binop1 = std::minus<T>(),
    const BinaryOp2& binop2 = std::plus<T>())
{
    if (input1.size() != input2.size())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
    }
    T output = init;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input1.size(); ++i)
    {
        output = std::invoke(binop2, output, std::invoke(binop1, input1.at(i), input2.at(i)));
    }
    return output;
}


The usage of two_input_map_reduce template function: euclidean_distance template function implementation

//  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
template<arithmetic ElementT = double>
constexpr static ElementT euclidean_distance(
    const Image<ElementT>& input1,
    const Image<ElementT>& input2
    )
{
    if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
    }
    return std::pow(two_input_map_reduce(std::execution::seq, input1.getImageData(), input2.getImageData(), ElementT{},
        [](auto&& element1, auto&& element2) {
            return std::pow(element1 - element2, 2,0);
        }), 0.5);
}



Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation in C++
//  Developed by Jimmy Hu

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

namespace TinyDIP
{
    struct RGB
    {
        std::uint8_t channels[3];
    };

    struct RGB_DOUBLE
    {
        double channels[3];
    };

    using GrayScale = std::uint8_t;

    struct HSV
    {
        double channels[3];    //  Range: 0 <= H < 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 255
    };

    struct BMPIMAGE
    {
        std::filesystem::path FILENAME;

        unsigned int XSIZE;
        unsigned int YSIZE;
        std::uint8_t FILLINGBYTE;
        std::uint8_t* IMAGE_DATA;
    };
    
    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458312/6667035
    template <typename>
    struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};

    template <typename ...T>
    struct is_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T>
    concept image_element_standard_floating_point_type =
        std::same_as<double, T>
        or std::same_as<float, T>
        or std::same_as<long double, T>
    ;

    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> or is_complex<T>::value;

    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.emplace_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            if (sizes.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image size vector is empty!");
            }
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(sizes),
                    std::ranges::cend(sizes),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    ));
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                 std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data = std::move(input);
            auto count = std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(sizes), std::ranges::cend(sizes), 1, std::multiplies());
            if (image_data.size() != count) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }


        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  at_without_boundary_check template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at_without_boundary_check(indexInput...));
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  get function implementation
        constexpr ElementT get(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set function implementation
        constexpr ElementT& set(const std::size_t index) noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr bool set(const TupleT location, const ElementT draw_value)
        {
            if (checkBoundaryTuple(location))
            {
                image_data[tuple_location_to_index(location)] = draw_value;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        //  cast template function implementation
        template<typename TargetT>
        constexpr Image<TargetT> cast()
        {
            std::vector<TargetT> output_data;
            output_data.resize(image_data.size());
            std::transform(
                std::ranges::cbegin(image_data),
                std::ranges::cend(image_data),
                std::ranges::begin(output_data),
                [](auto& input){ return static_cast<TargetT>(input); }
                );
            Image<TargetT> output(output_data, size);
            return output;
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }
  
        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize() const noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return size[index];
        }

        //  getStride function implementation
        constexpr std::size_t getStride(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            if(index == 0)
            {
                return std::size_t{1};
            }
            std::size_t output = std::size_t{1};
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            {
                output *= size[i];
            }
            return output;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        //  print function implementation
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 4)
            {
                for(std::size_t a = 0; a < size[3]; ++a)
                {
                    os << "group = " << a << "\n";
                    for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                        {
                            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                            {
                                //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                                os << +at(x, y, z, a) << separator;
                            }
                            os << "\n";
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
        {
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    os << "( ";
                    for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                    }
                    os << ")" << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            os << "\n";
            return;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }
        
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //  write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //  archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }
        
#endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

        //  checkBoundaryTuple template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr bool checkBoundaryTuple(const TupleT location)
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = std::tuple_size<TupleT>{};
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (std::cmp_greater_equal(index, size[parameter_pack_index]))
                    return false;
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
                return true;
            };
            return std::apply([&](auto&&... args) { return ((function(args))&& ...);}, location);
        }

        //  tuple_location_to_index template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr std::size_t tuple_location_to_index(TupleT location)
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;
            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                    position += index * stride;
                    stride *= size[i++];
                };
            std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {((update_position(args)), ...);}, location);
            return position;
        }

#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }
#endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;

    //  zeros template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto zeros(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = Image<ElementT>(sizes...);
        return output;
    }

    //  ones template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto ones(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = zeros<ElementT>(sizes...);
        output.setAllValue(1);
        return output;
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, typename Urbg, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    requires std::uniform_random_bit_generator<std::remove_reference_t<Urbg>>
    constexpr static auto rand(Urbg&& urbg, Sizes... sizes)
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Sizes) == 1)
        {
            return rand(std::forward<Urbg>(urbg), sizes..., sizes...);
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<ElementT> image_data((... * sizes));
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143753/6667035
            //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/294739/231235
            auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<ElementT>{};
            std::ranges::generate(image_data, [&dist, &urbg]() { return dist(urbg); });

            return Image<ElementT>{std::move(image_data), sizes...};
        }
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Size>
    inline auto rand(Size... size)
    {
        return rand<ElementT>(std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}, size...);
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, typename Urbg>
    requires std::uniform_random_bit_generator<std::remove_reference_t<Urbg>>
    constexpr auto rand(Urbg&& urbg) -> ElementT
    {
        auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<ElementT>{};
        return dist(urbg);
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double>
    inline auto rand()
    {
        return rand<ElementT>(std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    }

    //  two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation
    template<
        class ExecutionPolicy,
        std::ranges::input_range Input1,
        std::ranges::input_range Input2,
        class T,
        class BinaryOp1 = std::minus<T>,
        class BinaryOp2 = std::plus<T>
    >
    requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>)
    constexpr auto two_input_map_reduce(
        ExecutionPolicy execution_policy,
        const Input1& input1,
        const Input2& input2,
        const T init = {},
        const BinaryOp1& binop1 = std::minus<T>(),
        const BinaryOp2& binop2 = std::plus<T>())
    {
        if (input1.size() != input2.size())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        T output = init;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input1.size(); ++i)
        {
            output = std::invoke(binop2, output, std::invoke(binop1, input1.at(i), input2.at(i)));
        }
        return output;
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<arithmetic ElementT = double>
    constexpr static ElementT euclidean_distance(
        const Image<ElementT>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT>& input2
        )
    {
        if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        return std::pow(two_input_map_reduce(std::execution::seq, input1.getImageData(), input2.getImageData(), ElementT{},
            [](auto&& element1, auto&& element2) {
                return std::pow(element1 - element2, 2.0);
            }), 0.5);
    }
}

void euclidean_distanceTest(
    const std::size_t size = 10)
{
    auto image1 = TinyDIP::rand(size);
    image1.print();
    auto image2 = TinyDIP::rand(size);
    image2.print();
    std::cout << "euclidean_distance of image1 and image2: " << TinyDIP::euclidean_distance(image1, image2) << '\n';
    return;
}

int main()
{
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  euclidean_distanceTest();
  auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
  std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
  if (elapsed_seconds.count() != 1)
  {
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " second.\n";
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The output of the test code above:
0.942663    0.215227    0.854923    0.920088    0.822885    0.455803    0.306821    0.762646    0.750017    0.769243    
0.881823    0.0267963   0.263359    0.249576    0.262666    0.500275    0.892735    0.0591688   0.333526    0.249222    
0.230716    0.294099    0.92469 0.794454    0.671532    0.955971    0.96578 0.277482    0.923292    0.352687    
0.384754    0.815868    0.130012    0.990686    0.0764981   0.607916    0.100271    0.941067    0.591477    0.622292    
0.619941    0.0903779   0.3153  0.887376    0.712452    0.692778    0.799862    0.314102    0.36973 0.498771    
0.990471    0.62427 0.508855    0.174927    0.96172 0.280553    0.484737    0.651612    0.289279    0.519536    
0.5262  0.648017    0.30644 0.250521    0.0121238   0.651341    0.577217    0.551144    0.150986    0.400741    
0.553017    0.547173    0.777782    0.569329    0.238087    0.303304    0.80171 0.303825    0.871488    0.0114068   
0.820055    0.893761    0.861102    0.145328    0.33388 0.966593    0.251344    0.1323  0.221259    0.803391    
0.0483566   0.667218    0.660784    0.768977    0.692002    0.556829    0.637324    0.99033 0.505981    0.169241    

0.0911815   0.0364111   0.858391    0.758008    0.989485    0.257554    0.776529    0.841599    0.991322    0.99371 
0.948481    0.922639    0.908278    0.695429    0.832322    0.235193    0.308622    0.670952    0.00906573  0.263175    
0.0609413   0.76672 0.448044    0.54797 0.976732    0.00904112  0.671799    0.749321    0.389792    0.148507    
0.088823    0.203926    0.138408    0.191991    0.676849    0.355093    0.163111    0.559863    0.0356638   0.585218    
0.594333    0.542986    0.305012    0.750548    0.911332    0.911965    0.150223    0.735081    0.0439473   0.771634    
0.362987    0.833429    0.505483    0.956256    0.619084    0.520184    0.377139    0.806838    0.0585637   0.332734    
0.0974887   0.166464    0.919345    0.708126    0.233816    0.292142    0.233775    0.454393    0.564947    0.508596    
0.0899944   0.569735    0.899202    0.16578 0.576398    0.776669    0.531967    0.993786    0.831844    0.846377    
0.737224    0.844899    0.753622    0.711529    0.817064    0.629317    0.741225    0.190586    0.558096    0.888176    
0.585241    0.45716 0.913978    0.459305    0.522799    0.22649 0.938542    0.253976    0.463508    0.621812    

euclidean_distance of image1 and image2: 4.04981
Computation finished at Tue Dec 24 14:17:41 2024
elapsed time: 0.000254682 seconds.

Godbolt link is here.
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for Image in C++.

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to implement two_input_map_reduce template function in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
About naming, I am not sure the name two_input_map_reduce is good or not. All suggestions are welcome.



Compose it out of other algorithms
What if instead of two ranges, you want to reduce three ranges at the same time? Or fourtytwo? What if you want to filter elements and transform them before reducing? Would you want to implement a fourty_two_input_map_filter_transform_reduce()? The only sane way to handle this is to have a set of simple, basic algorithms that are composable.
In this case, your algorithm is actually composed of a binary transform followed by a reduce. So ideally you should be able to write it like so:
template<…>
requires …
constexpr auto two_input_map_reduce(
    ExecutionPolicy execution_policy,
    const Input1& input1,
    const Input2& input2,
    const T init = {},
    const BinaryOp1& binop1 = std::minus<T>(),
    const BinaryOp2& binop2 = std::plus<T>())
{
    return std::ranges::reduce(
        execution_policy,
        std::ranges::transform_view(input1, input2, binop1);
        init,
        binop2
    );
}

I already knew that there actually is no std::ranges::reduce() in the library yet, only a std::ranges::fold_left() which does not take an execution policy. But today I learned that std::ranges::transform_view only takes a single range as input, unlike std::ranges::transform() which allows binary transforms. However, we can compose our own binary transform view using a std::ranges::zip_view:
template<…>
requires …
constexpr auto two_input_map_reduce(
    ExecutionPolicy execution_policy,
    const Input1& input1,
    const Input2& input2,
    const T init = {},
    const BinaryOp1& binop1 = std::minus<T>(),
    const BinaryOp2& binop2 = std::plus<T>())
{
    auto transformed = std::views::zip(input1, input2)
                     | std::views::transform([&](auto input) {
                           return binop1(std::get<0>(input), std::get<1>(input));
                       });
    return std::reduce(
        execution_policy,
        transformed.begin(), transformed.end(),
        init,
        binop2
    );
}

Note how this version actually uses execution_policy, whereas your version does not.
Or just use std::transform_reduce()
I think you missed that std::transform_reduce() has an overload that takes two input ranges, and does exactly what you want it to do, except for the fact that it only works on iterators.
Try to match the STL algorithm interface exactly
If you look at the STL algorithms, note how they take the input ranges as forwarding references, and init by value. The operators should either be takes as forwarding references or by value. Consider that operators can be function objects that store state, so you want to handle them such that that state is not destroyed halfway during your algorithm.
Minor issues

std::pow(…, 0.5) is more commonly written as std::sqrt(…)
Don't use .at() if you already know you are not going to be out-of-bounds.
Your euclidean_distance() requires the output value to have the same type as the image values. But what if you want a floating point distance when you have images that are uint8_t? Or what if one image is float but the other is double?
Your code currently only works for images with a single channel. What if you have an RGB image? I still think it makes sense to talk about euclidian distance in that case. Maybe you want to support a projection operator, or just return an RGB value, where each component is the euclidian distance of that color.


> Or what if one image is float but the other is double? The current version of code requires user use cast method to make both image same type.

That sounds wasteful if it's a large image.
