apply_each_single_output Template Function Implementation for Image in C++
This is a follow-up question for two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation in C++ and euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for Image in C++. Considering the opinion from G. Sliepen's answer:

What if you have an RGB image? I still think it makes sense to talk about euclidian distance in that case.

I am trying to implement another overload euclidean_distance template function which returns an std::tuple for color image and I found that apply_each_single_output template function for computing each plane then get an output is what I need.
The experimental implementation

apply_each_single_output template function implementation
//  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<RGB>& input1, const Image<RGB>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
{
    auto Rresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Gresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Bresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
    return std::make_tuple(Rresult.get(), Gresult.get(), Bresult.get());
}

//  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input1, const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
{
    auto Rresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Gresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Bresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
    return std::make_tuple(Rresult.get(), Gresult.get(), Bresult.get());
}

//  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<HSV> input1, const Image<HSV> input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
{
    auto Hresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getHplane(input1), getHplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Sresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getSplane(input1), getSplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Vresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getVplane(input1), getVplane(input2), args...); });
    return std::make_tuple(Hresult.get(), Sresult.get(), Vresult.get());
}



Q&A

Question: Why using tuple as the return type, not RGB, RGB_DOUBLE or HSV as follows?
//  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
template<class F, class... Args>
constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<RGB>& input1, const Image<RGB>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
{
    auto Rresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Gresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
    auto Bresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
    return RGB{Rresult.get(), Gresult.get(), Bresult.get()};
}

Answer: Because there are various possible return types in each channel based on the input lambda function, it's bad to restrict type to only std::uint8_t,  double and double (which are the element type of RGB, RGB_DOUBLE and HSV, respectively).


Full Testing Code
The full testing code:
//  apply_each_single_output Template Function Implementation for Image in C++
//  Developed by Jimmy Hu

#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>
#include <concepts>
#include <execution>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

namespace TinyDIP
{
    struct RGB
    {
        std::uint8_t channels[3];

        inline RGB operator+(const RGB& input) const
        {
            return RGB{
                static_cast<std::uint8_t>(input.channels[0] + channels[0]),
                static_cast<std::uint8_t>(input.channels[1] + channels[1]),
                static_cast<std::uint8_t>(input.channels[2] + channels[2]) };
        }

        inline RGB operator-(const RGB& input) const
        {
            return RGB{
                static_cast<std::uint8_t>(channels[0] - input.channels[0]),
                static_cast<std::uint8_t>(channels[1] - input.channels[1]),
                static_cast<std::uint8_t>(channels[2] - input.channels[2]) };
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const RGB& _myStruct)
        {
            out << '{' << +_myStruct.channels[0] << ", " << +_myStruct.channels[1] << ", " << +_myStruct.channels[2] << '}';
            return out;
        }
    };

    struct RGB_DOUBLE
    {
        double channels[3];

        inline RGB_DOUBLE operator+(const RGB_DOUBLE& input) const
        {
            return RGB_DOUBLE{
                input.channels[0] + channels[0],
                input.channels[1] + channels[1],
                input.channels[2] + channels[2] };
        }

        inline RGB_DOUBLE operator-(const RGB_DOUBLE& input) const
        {
            return RGB_DOUBLE{
                channels[0] - input.channels[0],
                channels[1] - input.channels[1],
                channels[2] - input.channels[2] };
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const RGB_DOUBLE& _myStruct)
        {
            out << '{' << +_myStruct.channels[0] << ", " << +_myStruct.channels[1] << ", " << +_myStruct.channels[2] << '}';
            return out;
        }
    };

    using GrayScale = std::uint8_t;

    struct HSV
    {
        double channels[3];    //  Range: 0 <= H < 360, 0 <= S <= 1, 0 <= V <= 255

        inline HSV operator+(const HSV& input) const
        {
            return HSV{
                input.channels[0] + channels[0],
                input.channels[1] + channels[1],
                input.channels[2] + channels[2] };
        }

        inline HSV operator-(const HSV& input) const
        {
            return HSV{
                channels[0] - input.channels[0],
                channels[1] - input.channels[1],
                channels[2] - input.channels[2] };
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const HSV& _myStruct)
        {
            out << '{' << +_myStruct.channels[0] << ", " << +_myStruct.channels[1] << ", " << +_myStruct.channels[2] << '}';
            return out;
        }
    };

    struct BMPIMAGE
    {
        std::filesystem::path FILENAME;

        unsigned int XSIZE;
        unsigned int YSIZE;
        std::uint8_t FILLINGBYTE;
        std::uint8_t* IMAGE_DATA;
    };
    
    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458312/6667035
    template <typename>
    struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};

    template <typename ...T>
    struct is_tuple<std::tuple<T...>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T>
    concept image_element_standard_floating_point_type =
        std::same_as<double, T>
        or std::same_as<float, T>
        or std::same_as<long double, T>
    ;

    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64287611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

    template <typename T>
    struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

    //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067611/6667035
    template <typename T>
    concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> or is_complex<T>::value;

    //  recursive_print template function implementation
    template<typename T>
    constexpr void recursive_print(const T& input, const std::size_t level = 0)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << input << '\n';
    }

    template<std::ranges::input_range Range>
    constexpr void recursive_print(const Range& input, const std::size_t level = 0)
    {
        std::cout << std::string(level, ' ') << "Level " << level << ":" << std::endl;
        std::ranges::for_each(input, [level](auto&& element) {
            recursive_print(element, level + 1);
        });
    }

    template <typename ElementT>
    class Image
    {
    public:
        Image() = default;

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
        {}

        template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
        Image(Sizes... sizes)
        {
            size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
            (size.emplace_back(sizes), ...);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                    std::ranges::cend(size),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    )
            );
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            if (sizes.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image size vector is empty!");
            }
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data.resize(
                std::reduce(
                    std::ranges::cbegin(sizes),
                    std::ranges::cend(sizes),
                    std::size_t{1},
                    std::multiplies<>()
                    ));
        }

        template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                 std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
        Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, Sizes... sizes):
            size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }

        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, const std::vector<std::size_t>& sizes)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size = std::move(sizes);
            image_data = std::move(input);
            auto count = std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(sizes), std::ranges::cend(sizes), 1, std::multiplies());
            if (image_data.size() != count) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
        }


        Image(const std::vector<ElementT>& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(newWidth);
            size.emplace_back(newHeight);
            if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
            }
            image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
        }

        Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
        {
            if (input.empty())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Input vector is empty!");
            }
            size.reserve(2);
            size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
            size.emplace_back(input.size());
            for (auto& rows : input)
            {
                image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
            }
            return;
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
        }

        //  at template function implementation
        //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            checkBoundary(indexInput...);
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  at_without_boundary_check template function implementation
        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput)
        {
            return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at_without_boundary_check(indexInput...));
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        constexpr ElementT const& at_without_boundary_check(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;

            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                position += index * stride;
                stride *= size[i++];
            };
            (update_position(indexInput), ...);

            return image_data[position];
        }

        //  get function implementation
        constexpr ElementT get(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set function implementation
        constexpr ElementT& set(const std::size_t index) noexcept
        {
            return image_data[index];
        }

        //  set template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr bool set(const TupleT location, const ElementT draw_value)
        {
            if (checkBoundaryTuple(location))
            {
                image_data[tuple_location_to_index(location)] = draw_value;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        //  cast template function implementation
        template<typename TargetT>
        constexpr Image<TargetT> cast()
        {
            std::vector<TargetT> output_data;
            output_data.resize(image_data.size());
            std::transform(
                std::ranges::cbegin(image_data),
                std::ranges::cend(image_data),
                std::ranges::begin(output_data),
                [](auto& input){ return static_cast<TargetT>(input); }
                );
            Image<TargetT> output(output_data, size);
            return output;
        }

        constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
        {
            return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
        }
  
        constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
        {
            return size.size();
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
        {
            return size[0];
        }

        constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
        {
            return size[1];
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize() const noexcept
        {
            return size;
        }

        //  getSize function implementation
        constexpr auto getSize(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            return size[index];
        }

        //  getStride function implementation
        constexpr std::size_t getStride(std::size_t index) const noexcept
        {
            if(index == 0)
            {
                return std::size_t{1};
            }
            std::size_t output = std::size_t{1};
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            {
                output *= size[i];
            }
            return output;
        }

        std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

        //  print function implementation
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        {
            if(size.size() == 1)
            {
                for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                    os << +at(x) << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if(size.size() == 2)
            {
                for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                {
                    for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 3)
            {
                for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                {
                    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                        {
                            //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                            os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            else if (size.size() == 4)
            {
                for(std::size_t a = 0; a < size[3]; ++a)
                {
                    os << "group = " << a << "\n";
                    for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                    {
                        for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                        {
                            for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                            {
                                //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                                os << +at(x, y, z, a) << separator;
                            }
                            os << "\n";
                        }
                        os << "\n";
                    }
                    os << "\n";
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
        }

        //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
        void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
        requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
        {
            for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
            {
                for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                {
                    os << "( ";
                    for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                    {
                        //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                        os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                    }
                    os << ")" << separator;
                }
                os << "\n";
            }
            os << "\n";
            return;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
        {
            std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
            return *this;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            const std::string separator = "\t";
            rhs.print(separator, os);
            return os;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
        {
            check_size_same(rhs, *this);
            std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                   std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
            return *this;
        }

        friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

        friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 += input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
        {
            return input1 -= input2;
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input1, input2);
        }

        friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
        {
            return multiplies(input2, input1);
        }
        
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

        void Save(std::string filename)
        {
            const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
            std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
            //  write class instance to archive
            ArchiveOut << *this;
            //  archive and stream closed when destructors are called
            ofs.close();
        }
        
#endif
    private:
        std::vector<std::size_t> size;
        std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

        template<typename... Args>
        void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                    throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
            };

            (function(indexInput), ...);
        }

        //  checkBoundaryTuple template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr bool checkBoundaryTuple(const TupleT location)
        {
            constexpr std::size_t n = std::tuple_size<TupleT>{};
            if(n != size.size())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
            }
            std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
            auto function = [&](auto index) {
                if (std::cmp_greater_equal(index, size[parameter_pack_index]))
                    return false;
                parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
                return true;
            };
            return std::apply([&](auto&&... args) { return ((function(args))&& ...);}, location);
        }

        //  tuple_location_to_index template function implementation
        template<class TupleT>
        requires(is_tuple<TupleT>::value)
        constexpr std::size_t tuple_location_to_index(TupleT location)
        {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            std::size_t stride = 1;
            std::size_t position = 0;
            auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                    position += index * stride;
                    stride *= size[i++];
                };
            std::apply([&](auto&&... args) {((update_position(args)), ...);}, location);
            return position;
        }

#ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar& size;
            ar& image_data;
        }
#endif

    };

    template<typename T, typename ElementT>
    concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;

    //  zeros template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto zeros(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = Image<ElementT>(sizes...);
        return output;
    }

    //  ones template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    constexpr static auto ones(Sizes... sizes)
    {
        auto output = zeros<ElementT>(sizes...);
        output.setAllValue(1);
        return output;
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, typename Urbg, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
    requires std::uniform_random_bit_generator<std::remove_reference_t<Urbg>>
    constexpr static auto rand(Urbg&& urbg, Sizes... sizes)
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(Sizes) == 1)
        {
            return rand(std::forward<Urbg>(urbg), sizes..., sizes...);
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<ElementT> image_data((... * sizes));
            //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143753/6667035
            //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/294739/231235
            auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<ElementT>{};
            std::ranges::generate(image_data, [&dist, &urbg]() { return dist(urbg); });

            return Image<ElementT>{std::move(image_data), sizes...};
        }
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, std::same_as<std::size_t>... Size>
    inline auto rand(Size... size)
    {
        return rand<ElementT>(std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}, size...);
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double, typename Urbg>
    requires std::uniform_random_bit_generator<std::remove_reference_t<Urbg>>
    constexpr auto rand(Urbg&& urbg) -> ElementT
    {
        auto dist = std::uniform_real_distribution<ElementT>{};
        return dist(urbg);
    }

    //  rand template function implementation
    template<image_element_standard_floating_point_type ElementT = double>
    inline auto rand()
    {
        return rand<ElementT>(std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_width_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        if (!is_width_same(x, y))
            throw std::runtime_error("Width mismatched!");
    }

    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_height_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        if (!is_height_same(x, y))
            throw std::runtime_error("Height mismatched!");
    }

    //  check_size_same template function implementation
    template<typename ElementT>
    constexpr void check_size_same(const Image<ElementT>& x, const Image<ElementT>& y)
    {
        if(x.getSize() != y.getSize())
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
    }

    //  getPlane template function implementation
    template<class OutputT = unsigned char>
    constexpr static auto getPlane(const Image<RGB>& input, std::size_t index)
    {
        auto input_data = input.getImageData();
        std::vector<OutputT> output_data;
        output_data.resize(input.count());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.count(); ++i)
        {
            output_data[i] = input_data[i].channels[index];
        }
        auto output = Image<OutputT>(output_data, input.getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  getPlane template function implementation
    template<class T = HSV, class OutputT = double>
    requires (std::same_as<T, HSV> || std::same_as<T, RGB_DOUBLE>)
    constexpr static auto getPlane(const Image<T>& input, std::size_t index)
    {
        auto input_data = input.getImageData();
        std::vector<OutputT> output_data;
        output_data.resize(input.count());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < input.count(); ++i)
        {
            output_data[i] = input_data[i].channels[index];
        }
        auto output = Image<OutputT>(output_data, input.getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  getRplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getRplane(const Image<RGB>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 0);
    }

    //  getRplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getRplane(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 0);
    }

    //  getGplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getGplane(const Image<RGB>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 1);
    }

    //  getGplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getGplane(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 1);
    }

    //  getBplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getBplane(const Image<RGB>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 2);
    }

    //  getBplane function implementation
    constexpr static auto getBplane(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 2);
    }

    constexpr static auto getHplane(const Image<HSV>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 0);
    }

    constexpr static auto getSplane(const Image<HSV>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 1);
    }

    constexpr static auto getVplane(const Image<HSV>& input)
    {
        return getPlane(input, 2);
    }

    //  constructRGB template function implementation
    template<typename OutputT = RGB>
    constexpr static auto constructRGB(const Image<GrayScale>& r, const Image<GrayScale>& g, const Image<GrayScale>& b)
    {
        check_size_same(r, g);
        check_size_same(g, b);
        auto image_data_r = r.getImageData();
        auto image_data_g = g.getImageData();
        auto image_data_b = b.getImageData();
        std::vector<OutputT> new_data;
        new_data.resize(r.count());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < r.count(); ++index)
        {
            OutputT rgb {   image_data_r[index],
                        image_data_g[index],
                        image_data_b[index]};
            new_data[index] = rgb;
        }
        Image<OutputT> output(new_data, r.getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  constructRGBDOUBLE template function implementation
    template<typename OutputT = RGB_DOUBLE>
    constexpr static auto constructRGBDOUBLE(const Image<double>& r, const Image<double>& g, const Image<double>& b)
    {
        check_size_same(r, g);
        check_size_same(g, b);
        auto image_data_r = r.getImageData();
        auto image_data_g = g.getImageData();
        auto image_data_b = b.getImageData();
        std::vector<OutputT> new_data;
        new_data.resize(r.count());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < r.count(); ++index)
        {
            OutputT rgb_double { image_data_r[index],
                                    image_data_g[index],
                                    image_data_b[index]};
            new_data[index] = rgb_double;
        }
        Image<OutputT> output(new_data, r.getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  constructHSV template function implementation
    template<typename OutputT = HSV>
    constexpr static auto constructHSV(const Image<double>& h, const Image<double>& s, const Image<double>& v)
    {
        check_size_same(h, s);
        check_size_same(s, v);
        auto image_data_h = h.getImageData();
        auto image_data_s = s.getImageData();
        auto image_data_v = v.getImageData();
        std::vector<OutputT> new_data;
        new_data.resize(h.count());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < h.count(); ++index)
        {
            OutputT hsv {   image_data_h[index],
                        image_data_s[index],
                        image_data_v[index]};
            new_data[index] = hsv;
        }
        Image<OutputT> output(new_data, h.getSize());
        return output;
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(const Image<RGB>& input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input), args...); });
        auto Gplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input), args...); });
        auto Bplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input), args...); });
        return constructRGB(Rplane.get(), Gplane.get(), Bplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input), args...); });
        auto Gplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input), args...); });
        auto Bplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input), args...); });
        return constructRGBDOUBLE(Rplane.get(), Gplane.get(), Bplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(const Image<HSV>& input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Hplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getHplane(input), args...); });
        auto Splane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getSplane(input), args...); });
        auto Vplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getVplane(input), args...); });
        return constructHSV(Hplane.get(), Splane.get(), Vplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(const Image<RGB>& input1, const Image<RGB>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Gplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Bplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
        return constructRGB(Rplane.get(), Gplane.get(), Bplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input1, const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Gplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Bplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
        return constructRGBDOUBLE(Rplane.get(), Gplane.get(), Bplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(const Image<HSV> input1, const Image<HSV> input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Hplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getHplane(input1), getHplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Splane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getSplane(input1), getSplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Vplane = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getVplane(input1), getVplane(input2), args...); });
        return constructHSV(Hplane.get(), Splane.get(), Vplane.get());
    }

    //  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<RGB>& input1, const Image<RGB>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Gresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Bresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
        return std::make_tuple(Rresult.get(), Gresult.get(), Bresult.get());
    }

    //  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input1, const Image<RGB_DOUBLE>& input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Rresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getRplane(input1), getRplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Gresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getGplane(input1), getGplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Bresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getBplane(input1), getBplane(input2), args...); });
        return std::make_tuple(Rresult.get(), Gresult.get(), Bresult.get());
    }

    //  apply_each_single_output template function implementation
    template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each_single_output(const Image<HSV> input1, const Image<HSV> input2, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto Hresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getHplane(input1), getHplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Sresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getSplane(input1), getSplane(input2), args...); });
        auto Vresult = std::async(std::launch::async, [&] { return std::invoke(operation, getVplane(input1), getVplane(input2), args...); });
        return std::make_tuple(Hresult.get(), Sresult.get(), Vresult.get());
    }

    //  two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation
    template<
        class ExecutionPolicy,
        std::ranges::input_range Input1,
        std::ranges::input_range Input2,
        class T,
        class BinaryOp1 = std::minus<T>,
        class BinaryOp2 = std::plus<T>
    >
    requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExecutionPolicy>>)
    constexpr auto two_input_map_reduce(
        ExecutionPolicy execution_policy,
        const Input1& input1,
        const Input2& input2,
        const T init = {},
        const BinaryOp1& binop1 = std::minus<T>(),
        const BinaryOp2& binop2 = std::plus<T>())
    {
        if (input1.size() != input2.size())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        auto transformed = std::views::zip(input1, input2)
                     | std::views::transform([&](auto input) {
                           return std::invoke(binop1, std::get<0>(input), std::get<1>(input));
                       });
        return std::reduce(
            execution_policy,
            transformed.begin(), transformed.end(),
            init,
            binop2
        );
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<
        arithmetic OutputT = double,
        class ExPo,
        arithmetic ElementT1 = double,
        arithmetic ElementT2 = double
        >
    requires(std::is_execution_policy_v<std::remove_cvref_t<ExPo>>)
    constexpr static auto euclidean_distance(
        ExPo execution_policy,
        const Image<ElementT1>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT2>& input2,
        const OutputT output = 0.0
        )
    {
        if (input1.getSize() != input2.getSize())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatched!");
        }
        return std::sqrt(two_input_map_reduce(execution_policy, input1.getImageData(), input2.getImageData(), OutputT{},
            [&](auto&& element1, auto&& element2) {
                return std::pow(element1 - element2, 2.0);
            }));
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation
    template<
        arithmetic OutputT = double,
        arithmetic ElementT1 = double,
        arithmetic ElementT2 = double
        >
    constexpr static auto euclidean_distance(
        const Image<ElementT1>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT2>& input2,
        const OutputT output = 0.0
        )
    {
        return euclidean_distance(std::execution::seq, input1, input2, output);
    }

    //  euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for multiple channel image
    template<
        arithmetic OutputT = double,
        class ElementT1,
        class ElementT2
        >
    requires((std::same_as<ElementT1, RGB>) || (std::same_as<ElementT1, RGB_DOUBLE>) || (std::same_as<ElementT1, HSV>)) and
            ((std::same_as<ElementT2, RGB>) || (std::same_as<ElementT2, RGB_DOUBLE>) || (std::same_as<ElementT2, HSV>))
    constexpr static auto euclidean_distance(
        const Image<ElementT1>& input1,
        const Image<ElementT2>& input2,
        const OutputT output = 0.0
        )
    {
        return apply_each_single_output(input1, input2, [&](auto&& planes1, auto&& planes2) { return euclidean_distance(planes1, planes2, output); });
    }

    //  hypot Template Function Implementation
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr auto hypot(Args... args)
    {
        return std::sqrt((std::pow(args, 2.0) + ...));
    }

    //  Copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41171552
    template<class TupType, std::size_t... I>
    void print_tuple(const TupType& _tup, std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        std::cout << "(";
        (..., (std::cout << (I == 0? "" : ", ") << std::get<I>(_tup)));
        std::cout << ")\n";
    }

    template<class... T>
    void print_tuple(const std::tuple<T...>& _tup)
    {
        print_tuple(_tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
    }
}

void euclidean_distanceRGBTest(
    const std::size_t sizex = 3,
    const std::size_t sizey = 2
    )
{
    TinyDIP::Image<TinyDIP::RGB> image1(sizex, sizey);
    image1.setAllValue(TinyDIP::RGB{1, 2, 3});
    image1.print();
    TinyDIP::Image<TinyDIP::RGB> image2(sizex, sizey);
    image2.print();
    std::cout << "euclidean_distance of image1 and image2: " << '\n';
    TinyDIP::print_tuple(TinyDIP::euclidean_distance(image1, image2));
    return;
}

int main()
{
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  euclidean_distanceRGBTest();
  auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
  std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);
  if (elapsed_seconds.count() != 1)
  {
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " seconds.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Computation finished at " << std::ctime(&end_time) << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " second.\n";
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The output of the test code above:
( 1 2   3   )   ( 1 2   3   )   ( 1 2   3   )   
( 1 2   3   )   ( 1 2   3   )   ( 1 2   3   )   

( 0 0   0   )   ( 0 0   0   )   ( 0 0   0   )   
( 0 0   0   )   ( 0 0   0   )   ( 0 0   0   )   

euclidean_distance of image1 and image2: 
(2.44949, 4.89898, 7.34847)
Computation finished at Thu Dec 26 17:19:51 2024
elapsed time: 0.0002009 seconds.

Godbolt link is here.
All suggestions are welcome.
The summary information:

Which question it is a follow-up to?
two_input_map_reduce Template Function Implementation in C++ and
euclidean_distance Template Function Implementation for Image in C++.

What changes has been made in the code since last question?
I am trying to implement apply_each_single_output template function in this post.

Why a new review is being asked for?
Please check the implementation of apply_each_single_output template function and the related code.



Make it more generic
What if you add an RGB_FLOAT or CMYK type? What if the user of your code defines their own pixel type? Ideally, you should only have to write one version of apply_each_single_output() that works on all pixel types.
Consider that all of your currently defined multi-channel pixel types have an array named channels. Consider creating a function that given a pixel type, returns a std::tuple of each of the channels. Then you can use that inside apply_each_single_output(). It requires some puzzling with std::tuple_cat(), std::integer_sequence, std::apply() and fold expressions, but it can be done.
Alternative approach
When I said that the euclidian_distance() function should be able to handle multi-channel images somehow, I had something else in mind. Your approach might have some uses as well, but consider that it creates copies of each image plane and starts multiple threads, each operating on its own plane. This is not necessary, you should be able to do one linear pass over all the pixels in one thread.
You can do this is you create your own sqrt() and pow() functions that work on multi-channel values. That way your main algorithm is almost unchanged:
… auto euclidian_distance(…)
{
    …
    return sqrt(
        two_input_map_reduce(execution_policy,
                             input1.getImageData(),
                             input2.getImageData(),
                             OutputT{},
                             [&](auto&& element1, auto&& element2) {
                                 return pow(element1 - element2, 2.0);
                             }
        )
   );
}

Now you just need to add those functions:
namespace TinyDIP
{
    template<typename T>
    concept Multichannel = requires(T a)
    {
        { a.channels }; // or whatever is best to check for multiple channels
    };

    template<typename T>
    auto sqrt(const T& input)
    {
        if constexpr (Multichannel<T>)
        {
            // return tuple of component-wise `std::sqrt`
        }
        else
        {
            return std::sqrt(input);
        }
    }

    // Same for pow()
    …     
}   

Another option would be to not rely on a component-wise subtraction, but to define a distance function that given two multi-channel values, returns a scalar distance.
