# Gaussian Fisheye Image Generator Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, template, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288719/231235) and [Three dimensional gaussian image generator in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288554/231235). I am trying to make a Gaussian fisheye image generator in this post. The example output:

| Image Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Input] | [image: Gaussian fisheye image generator output] |

**The experimental implementation**

- `gaussian_fisheye` template function implementation (in file `image_operations.h`)

  ```
  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      //  gaussian_fisheye template function implementation
      template<arithmetic ElementT, std::floating_point FloatingType = double>
      constexpr static auto gaussian_fisheye(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType D0)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }

          Image<ElementT> output(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
          for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
          {
              for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
              {
                  FloatingType distance_x = x - static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getWidth()) / 2.0;
                  FloatingType distance_y = y - static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getHeight()) / 2.0;
                  FloatingType distance = std::hypot(distance_x, distance_y);
                  FloatingType angle = std::atan2(distance_y, distance_x);
                  FloatingType weight = normalDistribution2D(std::fabs(distance_x), std::fabs(distance_y), D0) / normalDistribution2D(0.0, 0.0, D0);
                  FloatingType new_distance = distance * weight;
                  FloatingType new_distance_x = new_distance * std::cos(angle);
                  FloatingType new_distance_y = new_distance * std::sin(angle);
                  output.at(
                      static_cast<std::size_t>(new_distance_x + static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getWidth()) / 2.0),
                      static_cast<std::size_t>(new_distance_y + static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getHeight()) / 2.0)) = 
                      input.at(x, y);
              }
          }
          return output;
      }

      //  gaussian_fisheye template function implementation
      template<typename ElementT, class FloatingType = double>
      requires ((std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>) || (std::same_as<ElementT, HSV>))
      constexpr static auto gaussian_fisheye(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType D0)
      {
          return apply_each(input, [&](auto&& planes) { return gaussian_fisheye(planes, D0); });
      }
  }
  ```
- `normalDistribution2D` function implementation (in file `image_operations.h`)

  ```
  template<typename T>
  T normalDistribution2D(const T xlocation, const T ylocation, const T standard_deviation)
  {
      return std::exp(-(xlocation * xlocation + ylocation * ylocation) / (2 * standard_deviation * standard_deviation)) / (2 * std::numbers::pi * standard_deviation * standard_deviation);
  }
  ```
- `apply_each` function implementation (in file `image_operations.h`)

  ```
  template<class T = RGB, class F, class... Args>
  requires (std::same_as<T, RGB>)
  constexpr static auto apply_each(Image<T> input, F operation, Args&&... args)
  {
      return constructRGB(operation(getRplane(input), args...), operation(getGplane(input), args...), operation(getBplane(input), args...));
  }
  ```
- `Image` class implementation (in file `image.h`)

  ```
  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      template <typename ElementT>
      class Image
      {
      public:
          Image() = default;

          template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
          Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
          {}

          template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
          Image(Sizes... sizes)
          {
              size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
              (size.push_back(sizes), ...);
              image_data.resize(
                  std::reduce(
                      std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                      std::ranges::cend(size),
                      std::size_t{1},
                      std::multiplies<>()
                      )
              );
          }

          template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                   std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
          Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
              size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
          {
              if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
              }
          }

          Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(newWidth);
              size.emplace_back(newHeight);
              if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
              }
              image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
          }

          Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
              size.emplace_back(input.size());
              for (auto& rows : input)
              {
                  image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
              }
              return;
          }

          //  at template function implementation
          template<typename... Args>
          constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
          {
              return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
          }

          //  at template function implementation
          //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
          template<typename... Args>
          constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
          {
              checkBoundary(indexInput...);
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              std::size_t i = 0;
              std::size_t stride = 1;
              std::size_t position = 0;

              auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                  position += index * stride;
                  stride *= size[i++];
              };
              (update_position(indexInput), ...);

              return image_data[position];
          }

          constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
          {
              return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
          {
              return size.size();
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
          {
              return size[0];
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
          {
              return size[1];
          }

          constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
          {
              return size;
          }

          std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

          void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
          {
              if(size.size() == 1)
              {
                  for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                  {
                      //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                      os << +at(x) << separator;
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              else if(size.size() == 2)
              {
                  for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                  {
                      for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                      {
                          //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                          os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                      }
                      os << "\n";
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              else if (size.size() == 3)
              {
                  for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                  {
                      for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                      {
                          for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                          {
                              //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                              os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                          }
                          os << "\n";
                      }
                      os << "\n";
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
          }

          //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
          void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
          requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
          {
              for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
              {
                  for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                  {
                      os << "( ";
                      for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                      {
                          //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                          os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                      }
                      os << ")" << separator;
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              os << "\n";
              return;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
          {
              std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
              return *this;
          }

          friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              const std::string separator = "\t";
              rhs.print(separator, os);
              return os;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

          friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

          friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
          {
              return input1 += input2;
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
          {
              return input1 -= input2;
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
          {
              return multiplies(input1, input2);
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
          {
              return multiplies(input2, input1);
          }

  #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

          void Save(std::string filename)
          {
              const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
              //    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
              std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
              boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
              //    write class instance to archive
              ArchiveOut << *this;
              //    archive and stream closed when destructors are called
              ofs.close();
          }

  #endif
      private:
          std::vector<std::size_t> size;
          std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

          template<typename... Args>
          void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
          {
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
              auto function = [&](auto index) {
                  if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                  parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
              };

              (function(indexInput), ...);
          }

  #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
          friend class boost::serialization::access;
          template<class Archive>
          void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
          {
              ar& size;
              ar& image_data;
          }
  #endif

      };

      template<typename T, typename ElementT>
      concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;
  }


  #endif
  ```

The usage of `gaussian_fisheye` function:

```
std::string file_path = "InputImages/1";
auto bmp1 = TinyDIP::bmp_read(file_path.c_str(), false);
bmp1 = gaussian_fisheye(bmp1, 800.0);
TinyDIP::bmp_write("test", bmp1);
```

[TinyDIP on GitHub](https://github.com/Jimmy-Hu/TinyDIP)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288719/231235) and

  [Three dimensional gaussian image generator in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288554/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement `gaussian_fisheye` template function in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review the implementation of `gaussian_fisheye` template function.

Comment: Just like in your new question, here you should also iterate over the output image, and compute the corresponding location in the input. Otherwise either you write each output pixel multiple times, or you skip some output pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unnecessary calculations

You calculate `angle` using `std::atan2()`, but later use `std::cos()` and `std::sin()` to convert it back into x and y coordinates. This is unnecessary, you already had those to begin with, you only need to scale them.

Furthermore, you don't need to use `std::fabs()` before passing the x and y position to `normalDistribution2D()`, since it will square those values anyway.

Finally, you don't need any of the static casts to `FloatingType`, only the final casts back to `std::size_t`. So:

```
FloatingType distance_x = x - input.getWidth() / 2.0;
FloatingType distance_y = y - input.getHeight() / 2.0;
FloatingType weight = normalDistribution2D(distance_x, distance_y, D0)
                    / normalDistribution2D(0, 0, D0);
FloatingType new_distance_x = distance_x * weight;
FloatingType new_distance_y = distance_y * weight;
output.at(static_cast<std::size_t>(new_distance_x + input.getWidth() / 2.0),
          static_cast<std::size_t>(new_distance_y + input.getHeight() / 2.0)) =
    input.at(x, y);
```

Comment: > _`normalDistribution2D(0, 0, …)` is always equal to 1._ Nope, its value still depends on the standard deviation

Comment: Oh, I thought everything was inside the `std::exp()`...