# Image Rotation and Transpose Functions Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, matrix, c++20

This is a follow-up question for [Gaussian Fisheye Image Generator Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/291059/231235) and [An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288719/231235). I am trying to implement image rotation function in this post. The example output:

| Image Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Input] | [image: rotatedImage] |

**The experimental implementation**

- `rotate`, `rotate_detail` and `rotate_degree` template functions implementation (in file `image_operations.h`)

  `rotate_detail` template function performs image rotation operation between 0° to 90°.

  ```
  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      //  rotate_detail template function implementation
      //  rotate_detail template function performs image rotation between 0° to 90°
      template<arithmetic ElementT, std::floating_point FloatingType = double>
      constexpr static auto rotate_detail(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType radians)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }
          //  if 0° rotation case
          if (radians == 0)
          {
              return input;
          }
          //  if 90° rotation case
          if(radians == std::numbers::pi_v<long double> / 2.0)
          {
              Image<ElementT> output(input.getHeight(), input.getWidth());
              for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
              {
                  for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
                  {
                      output.at(input.getHeight() - y - 1, x) = 
                          input.at(x, y);
                  }
              }
              return output;
          }

          FloatingType half_width = static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getWidth()) / 2.0;
          FloatingType half_height = static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getHeight()) / 2.0;
          FloatingType new_width = 2 * 
              std::hypot(half_width, half_height) *
              std::abs(std::sin(std::atan2(half_width, half_height) + radians));
          FloatingType new_height = 2 *
              std::hypot(half_width, half_height) *
              std::abs(std::sin(std::atan2(half_height, half_width) + radians));

          Image<ElementT> output(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight());
          for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
          {
              for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
              {

                  FloatingType distance_x = x - half_width;
                  FloatingType distance_y = y - half_height;
                  FloatingType distance = std::hypot(distance_x, distance_y);
                  FloatingType angle = std::atan2(distance_y, distance_x) + radians;

                  FloatingType width_ratio = new_width / static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getWidth());
                  FloatingType height_ratio = new_height / static_cast<FloatingType>(input.getHeight());
                  FloatingType distance_weight = (input.getWidth() > input.getHeight())?(1 / height_ratio):(1 / width_ratio);
                  FloatingType new_distance = distance * distance_weight;
                  FloatingType new_distance_x = new_distance * std::cos(angle);
                  FloatingType new_distance_y = new_distance * std::sin(angle);
                  output.at(
                      static_cast<std::size_t>(new_distance_x + half_width),
                      static_cast<std::size_t>(new_distance_y + half_height)) = 
                      input.at(x, y);
              }
          }
          return output;
      }

      //  rotate template function implementation
      template<arithmetic ElementT, std::floating_point FloatingType = double>
      constexpr static auto rotate(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType radians)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }
          auto output = input;
          while(radians >= 2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double>)
          {
              radians = radians - 2 * std::numbers::pi_v<long double>;
          }
          while(radians > std::numbers::pi_v<long double> / 2.0)
          {
              output = rotate_detail(output, std::numbers::pi_v<long double> / 2.0);
              radians-=(std::numbers::pi_v<long double> / 2.0);
          }
          output = rotate_detail(output, radians);
          return output;
      }

      //  rotate template function implementation
      template<typename ElementT, class FloatingType = double>
      requires ((std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>) || (std::same_as<ElementT, HSV>))
      constexpr static auto rotate(const Image<ElementT>& input, FloatingType radians)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }
          return apply_each(input, [&](auto&& planes) { return rotate(planes, radians); });
      }

      //  rotate template function implementation
      template<arithmetic ElementT, std::integral T = int>
      constexpr static auto rotate(const Image<ElementT>& input, T radians)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }
          return rotate(input, static_cast<double>(radians));
      }

      //  rotate_degree template function implementation
      template<typename ElementT, class T = double>
      constexpr static auto rotate_degree(const Image<ElementT>& input, T degrees)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }
          return rotate(input, static_cast<double>(degrees) * std::numbers::pi_v<long double> / 180.0);
      }
  }
  ```
- `transpose` template function implementation (in file `image_operations.h`)

  ```
  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      //  transpose template function implementation
      template<typename ElementT>
      constexpr static auto transpose(const Image<ElementT>& input)
      {
          if (input.getDimensionality()!=2)
          {
              throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported dimension!");
          }
          Image<ElementT> output(input.getHeight(), input.getWidth());
          for (std::size_t y = 0; y < input.getHeight(); ++y)
          {
              for (std::size_t x = 0; x < input.getWidth(); ++x)
              {
                  output.at(y, x) = 
                      input.at(x, y);
              }
          }
          return output;
      }
  }
  ```
- `Image` class implementation (in file `image.h`)

  ```
  namespace TinyDIP
  {
      template <typename ElementT>
      class Image
      {
      public:
          Image() = default;

          template<std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
          Image(Sizes... sizes): size{sizes...}, image_data((1 * ... * sizes))
          {}

          template<std::same_as<int>... Sizes>
          Image(Sizes... sizes)
          {
              size.reserve(sizeof...(sizes));
              (size.push_back(sizes), ...);
              image_data.resize(
                  std::reduce(
                      std::ranges::cbegin(size),
                      std::ranges::cend(size),
                      std::size_t{1},
                      std::multiplies<>()
                      )
              );
          }

          template<std::ranges::input_range Range,
                   std::same_as<std::size_t>... Sizes>
          Image(const Range& input, Sizes... sizes):
              size{sizes...}, image_data(begin(input), end(input))
          {
              if (image_data.size() != (1 * ... * sizes)) {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
              }
          }

          Image(std::vector<ElementT>&& input, std::size_t newWidth, std::size_t newHeight)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(newWidth);
              size.emplace_back(newHeight);
              if (input.size() != newWidth * newHeight)
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Image data input and the given size are mismatched!");
              }
              image_data = std::move(input);              //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706522/6667035
          }

          Image(const std::vector<std::vector<ElementT>>& input)
          {
              size.reserve(2);
              size.emplace_back(input[0].size());
              size.emplace_back(input.size());
              for (auto& rows : input)
              {
                  image_data.insert(image_data.end(), std::ranges::begin(input), std::ranges::end(input));    //  flatten
              }
              return;
          }

          //  at template function implementation
          template<typename... Args>
          constexpr ElementT& at(const Args... indexInput)
          {
              return const_cast<ElementT&>(static_cast<const Image &>(*this).at(indexInput...));
          }

          //  at template function implementation
          //  Reference: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288736/231235
          template<typename... Args>
          constexpr ElementT const& at(const Args... indexInput) const
          {
              checkBoundary(indexInput...);
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              std::size_t i = 0;
              std::size_t stride = 1;
              std::size_t position = 0;

              auto update_position = [&](auto index) {
                  position += index * stride;
                  stride *= size[i++];
              };
              (update_position(indexInput), ...);

              return image_data[position];
          }

          constexpr std::size_t count() const noexcept
          {
              return std::reduce(std::ranges::cbegin(size), std::ranges::cend(size), 1, std::multiplies());
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getDimensionality() const noexcept
          {
              return size.size();
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getWidth() const noexcept
          {
              return size[0];
          }

          constexpr std::size_t getHeight() const noexcept
          {
              return size[1];
          }

          constexpr auto getSize() noexcept
          {
              return size;
          }

          std::vector<ElementT> const& getImageData() const noexcept { return image_data; }      //  expose the internal data

          void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
          {
              if(size.size() == 1)
              {
                  for(std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                  {
                      //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                      os << +at(x) << separator;
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              else if(size.size() == 2)
              {
                  for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                  {
                      for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                      {
                          //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                          os << +at(x, y) << separator;
                      }
                      os << "\n";
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              else if (size.size() == 3)
              {
                  for(std::size_t z = 0; z < size[2]; ++z)
                  {
                      for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
                      {
                          for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                          {
                              //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                              os << +at(x, y, z) << separator;
                          }
                          os << "\n";
                      }
                      os << "\n";
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
          }

          //  Enable this function if ElementT = RGB
          void print(std::string separator = "\t", std::ostream& os = std::cout) const
          requires(std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>)
          {
              for (std::size_t y = 0; y < size[1]; ++y)
              {
                  for (std::size_t x = 0; x < size[0]; ++x)
                  {
                      os << "( ";
                      for (std::size_t channel_index = 0; channel_index < 3; ++channel_index)
                      {
                          //  Ref: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/input-output#print-char-or-ptr-as-number
                          os << +at(x, y).channels[channel_index] << separator;
                      }
                      os << ")" << separator;
                  }
                  os << "\n";
              }
              os << "\n";
              return;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& setAllValue(const ElementT input)
          {
              std::fill(std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::ranges::end(image_data), input);
              return *this;
          }

          friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              const std::string separator = "\t";
              rhs.print(separator, os);
              return os;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator+=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::plus<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator-=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::minus<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator*=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::multiplies<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          Image<ElementT>& operator/=(const Image<ElementT>& rhs)
          {
              check_size_same(rhs, *this);
              std::transform(std::ranges::cbegin(image_data), std::ranges::cend(image_data), std::ranges::cbegin(rhs.image_data),
                     std::ranges::begin(image_data), std::divides<>{});
              return *this;
          }

          friend bool operator==(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

          friend bool operator!=(Image<ElementT> const&, Image<ElementT> const&) = default;

          friend Image<ElementT> operator+(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
          {
              return input1 += input2;
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator-(Image<ElementT> input1, const Image<ElementT>& input2)
          {
              return input1 -= input2;
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator*(Image<ElementT> input1, ElementT input2)
          {
              return multiplies(input1, input2);
          }

          friend Image<ElementT> operator*(ElementT input1, Image<ElementT> input2)
          {
              return multiplies(input2, input1);
          }

  #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION

          void Save(std::string filename)
          {
              const std::string filename_with_extension = filename + ".dat";
              //    Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c
              std::ofstream ofs(filename_with_extension, std::ios::binary);
              boost::archive::binary_oarchive ArchiveOut(ofs);
              //    write class instance to archive
              ArchiveOut << *this;
              //    archive and stream closed when destructors are called
              ofs.close();
          }

  #endif
      private:
          std::vector<std::size_t> size;
          std::vector<ElementT> image_data;

          template<typename... Args>
          void checkBoundary(const Args... indexInput) const
          {
              constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
              if(n != size.size())
              {
                  throw std::runtime_error("Dimensionality mismatched!");
              }
              std::size_t parameter_pack_index = 0;
              auto function = [&](auto index) {
                  if (index >= size[parameter_pack_index])
                      throw std::out_of_range("Given index out of range!");
                  parameter_pack_index = parameter_pack_index + 1;
              };

              (function(indexInput), ...);
          }

  #ifdef USE_BOOST_SERIALIZATION
          friend class boost::serialization::access;
          template<class Archive>
          void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
          {
              ar& size;
              ar& image_data;
          }
  #endif

      };

      template<typename T, typename ElementT>
      concept is_Image = std::is_same_v<T, Image<ElementT>>;
  }


  #endif
  ```

The usage of `rotate` function:

```
std::string file_path = "InputImages/1";
auto bmp1 = TinyDIP::bmp_read(file_path.c_str(), false);
bmp1 = rotate(bmp1, 1.0);
TinyDIP::bmp_write("test", bmp1);
```

The usage `transpose` function:

```
template<typename ElementT>
void transposeTest(const size_t size = 5)
{
    std::cout << "Test with 2D image:\n";
    auto image2d = TinyDIP::Image<ElementT>(size, size);
    image2d.setAllValue(1);
    image2d.at(0, 1) = 3;
    image2d.print();
    TinyDIP::transpose(image2d).print();
    
    return;
}
```

[Godbolt link is here.](https://godbolt.org/z/1a9j4ajMv)

[TinyDIP on GitHub](https://github.com/Jimmy-Hu/TinyDIP)

All suggestions are welcome.

The summary information:

- Which question it is a follow-up to?

  [Gaussian Fisheye Image Generator Implementation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/291059/231235) and

  [An Updated Multi-dimensional Image Data Structure with Variadic Template Functions in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288719/231235)
- What changes has been made in the code since last question?

  I am trying to implement image rotation and transpose function in this post.
- Why a new review is being asked for?

  Please review the implementation of `rotate` and `transpose` template functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Avoid trigonometric functions where possible

Trigonometric functions like `atan2()`, `sin()` and `cos()` are very slow. You do three of those operations per pixel, which is going to be the major performance issue with your code.

There is a way to avoid doing any per-pixel trigonometry though, and that is by decomposing the rotation into three shear operations, like for example shown in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909025/rotating-a-bitmap-with-3-shears).

## Loop over the output pixels

You loop over the input pixels, and remap their coordinates to the output. However, you will then have a risk that you miss some output pixels, as some might be skipped due to floating point rounding. Maybe you get lucky most of the time, but to avoid the problem, loop over the output pixels, and remap their coordinates to the input to find out which color to copy.

Even better, if you use the shearing technique then you can avoid this issue completely.

## Handle negative rotation angles

`rotate()` seems to only check for `radians` being too large in the positive direction, but doesn't check for potentially large negative values.

I also recommend you use [`std::fmod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) or something similar to truncate the angle here, instead of using a `while`-loop.

## Avoid rotating up to four times

If the angle is between \$1\frac{1}{2} \pi\$ and \$2 \pi\$, you are performing four rotations. You should be able to rotate everything in one go (or if you use shear operations, using not more than 3 shears).

If your algorithm really can't handle rotations larger than 90 degrees, then at least implement a fast algorithm to do 90, 180 and 270 degree rotations, as these are trivial to implement.

Comment: *"decomposing the rotation into three shear operations, like for example shown in this StackOverflow question."* - Matt Parker did a video on this very recently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LCEiVDHJmc. No affiliation, just a demonstration I thought was neat.

Comment: Another advantage of the three sheer technique is that you interpolate in 1D only, which is much simpler than interpolating in 2D when sampling a pixel at an arbitrary location in the image.

Comment: @G. Sliepen Thank you for letting me know the shearing technique. It looks good to deal with image rotation with it. :)

Answer (score 2):

[G. Sliepen already pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/291254/151754) the three sheer technique, the need to iterate over the output pixels rather than the input, and the expense of doing large rotations 90 degrees at the time. There are a few things to add here:

1. The three sheer technique is not only cheaper, it also makes adding interpolation very easy, as all you do is shift lines of pixels over by a certain distance.
2. You do a lot of computation repeatedly inside the loop, you should move these outside the loop. For example, rotated coordinates are computed by multiplying the input coordinates by a [rotation matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), which is fixed for the whole operation. So inside the loop all you have is four multiplications and two additions to rotate each coordinate. Though of course you should iterate over the output image, and so you use the inverse rotation matrix (or negate the angle) to find the input coordinate corresponding to each output pixel.
3. Indexing using `.at(x,y)` is quite expensive. To access an arbitrary element it is great, but in a loop that iterates over each pixel, it is much cheaper to add one to the pointer for one pixel to get to the next pixel. You also don’t want to continuously test for indices being inside the bounds, you already know they are.
4. `requires ((std::same_as<ElementT, RGB>) || (std::same_as<ElementT, HSV>))` means that you need to rewrite this function (and all the other ones in the library that do a similar thing) if you ever decide to add a color space. I would suggest making this more generic for all color images. Maybe have a base class for both RGB and HSV, that you can use in the requirement?

---

PS: looking up the definition of `apply_each` in your repo (it’s not included in the question), I see:

```cpp
template<class T = RGB, class F, class... Args>
    requires (std::same_as<T, RGB>)
    constexpr static auto apply_each(Image<T> input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {…}
```

That requirement makes `T` not a template parameter. Prefer:

```cpp
template<class F, class... Args>
    constexpr static auto apply_each(Image<RGB> input, F operation, Args&&... args)
    {…}
```

Just because it’s so much simpler. Also:

```cpp
template<class T = RGB>
    requires (std::same_as<T, RGB>)
    constexpr static auto getRplane(Image<T> input)
    {…}
```

This is not a template at all, just do:

```cpp
    constexpr static auto getRplane(Image<RGB> input)
    {…}
```

Comment: _> (Image<RGB> input...)_ makes `error: 'input' has incomplete type` error.

Comment: I think it's called "partial template specialization" and it is not allowed.

Comment: @JimmyHu Do you mean in `apply_each`? You'd have to update each of the templates in the same way

Comment: Yes, I already updated each of `apply_each` templates in the same way but the error is still occurred.

Comment: @JimmyHu I don't see why this wouldn't work. I just tried it myself in a little test program and it worked for me. Even changing only one `apply_each` in this way and not the other seems fine. The "incomplete type" error is likely related to trying to instantiate a type that has been forward-declared but not fully defined. Try to avoid forward declarations, this error will go away.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I removed forward declarations and the issue resolved. Thank you.

Comment: About the 4th point, _> Maybe have a base class for both RGB and HSV..._ Is there any example available for this case?

Comment: @JimmyHu The templated image processing libraries I know do something like `Image<vec3<float>>` for color images, without specifying the color space. In your case I was thinking of `struct Color {}; struct RGB : Color { uint8 value[3]; };` and so on. Then you can still do `Image<RGB>`, but in your templated functions you can restrict to T being derived from `Color`. There might be other solutions. But you do want to avoid listing all the color spaces your library knows for every function that applies generically to color images.